# Get the last character of a string without using array?

Tags: swift, string

I have a string

```
let stringPlusString = TextBoxCal.text
```

I want to get the last character of `stringPlusString`. I do not want to use array.

Java has `charAt` but I could not find something similar in Swift

Comment: Swift isn't Java, that's why. Look at [this awesome blog post](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-strings/).

Comment: Ofc i know swift isn't java i just give a example if java exist like this method %100 swift exist too .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get nth character of a string in Swift programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language)

Comment: yes this method possible but i think, %100 must be exist any method for get a last character am i wrong ? java exist , c# exist, swift should be exist ?

Comment: @MartinR I think this is a special case: there's a more efficient way to get the last character of a string from the endIndex than to get the nth character in general. Some of the solutions to that question will be awful for this case, as they iterate from the beginning of the string.

Comment: @MattGibson: I thought that it can be derived easily from the answers given there, but you might be right. Closing vote retracted.

Comment: @MattGibson: But I am not completely sure if `advance(text.endIndex, -1)` really performs better. With the new support for extended grapheme clusters (e.g. "flags") it *might* be necessary to iterate from the start of the string anyway to determine the last character correctly.

Comment: Yup, that's a fair point. Though I'd hope in the end that at least endIndex might be cached on first use and only reset if the String changed. If I had time I'd do some benchmarking right now...

Comment: @vacawama: The [swift3] and [swift4] tags are for *"questions **directly related to changes** in version 3/4 of Apple's Swift programming language"*. I don't think that these tags should be added to a question if an answer has been updated for newer Swift versions.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

**Using `last` to get the last `Character`**

For **Swift 4**:

```
let str = "hello world"
let lastChar = str.last!   // lastChar is ""
```

For **Swift 2** and **Swift 3**:

```
let str = "hello world"
let lastChar = str.characters.last!   // lastChar is ""
```

For **Swift 1.2**:

```
let str = "hello world"
let lastChar = last(str)!   // lastChar is ""
```

---

**Subscripting the `String` to get the last `Character`**

This works for **Swift 3** and **Swift 4**:

```
let str = "hello world"
let lastChar = str[str.index(before: str.endIndex)]   // lastChar is ""
```

And for **Swift 1.2** and **Swift 2**:

```
let str = "hello world"
let lastChar = str[str.endIndex.predecessor()]   // lastChar is ""
```

Answer (score 16):

Swift 4:

First some char
Last some char

```
let strOSName = "mac operating system"
print(strOSName.prefix(3))       //first char. o/p:  MAC
print(strOSName.suffix(6))       //last char.  o/p:  system
```

Answer (score 6):

"**Without** using Array on swift"

Here you go:

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum"
var lastChar = text.substringFromIndex(text.endIndex.predecessor())
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    let text = "Muhammad Raza"
    println("\(text[advance(text.endIndex, -1)])")
```

in Short !

Answer (score 3):

### Details

- Swift 5.1, Xcode 11.2.1

### Solution

```
extension String {
    func onlyLastCharacters(_ count: Int) -> String { return String(suffix(count)) }
    func onlyLastCharacters(_ count: Int, checkLength: Bool) -> String? {
        if checkLength {
            if self.count >= count { return onlyLastCharacters(count) }
            return nil
        }
        return String(suffix(count))
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
str.onlyLastCharacters(6)
str.onlyLastCharacters(13, checkLength: true)
```

### Full sample

> Do not forget to **paste here the solution code**

```
var testNumber = 0
func show(original: String, modified: String?) {
    testNumber += 1
    if let string = modified {
        print("\(testNumber). Original: \"\(original)\", modified: \"\(string)\"")
    } else {
        print("\(testNumber). nil | count: nil")
    }
}

var str = "Hello world!"
show(original: str, modified: str.onlyLastCharacters(6))
show(original: str, modified: str.onlyLastCharacters(12))
show(original: str, modified: str.onlyLastCharacters(13, checkLength: false))
show(original: str, modified: str.onlyLastCharacters(13, checkLength: true))

str = ""
show(original: str, modified: str.onlyLastCharacters(10))
show(original: str, modified: str.onlyLastCharacters(10, checkLength: true))
show(original: str, modified: str.onlyLastCharacters(10, checkLength: false))
```

### Log

```
1. Original: "Hello world!", modified: "world!"
2. Original: "Hello world!", modified: "Hello world!"
3. Original: "Hello world!", modified: "Hello world!"
4. nil | count: nil
5. Original: "", modified: ""
6. nil | count: nil
7. Original: "", modified: ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another shorter way to get the last letter from string:

```
let text = "some string"
last(text) // returns {Some "a"}
```

The method last() returns an optional Character.