# Range(0...4) and substringWithRange?

Tags: ios, swift

I have to say that for a "modern" language Swift certainly makes a meal of specifying a range to capture a substring.
**My question:** Is there a way to create a `<String.Index>` using `Range(0...4)` or indeed a way to cast the result (of type `<Int>`) so that it can be used with `substringWithRange`?

```
let myString = "HappyDays"
var rangeString = Range(start: advance(myString.startIndex, 5), end: advance(myString.endIndex, -1))
myString.substringWithRange(rangeString) // >>> "Day"
```

.

```
// Can this be used to generate a range for substringWithRange?
var hardRange = Range(0...4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an extension on string e.g. [stackoverflow.com/a/24144365/1032372](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24144365/1032372)