# How to compare string.characterAtIndex with letter?

Tags: ios, swift

I use swift and what i want to do is to check this:

```
if string.characterAtIndex(i) == "a"
```

But i get error. How to convert this "a" so that can be same type with characters i loop.
Thanks.

Comment: *"But i get error."* What error, do we have to guess? How is `string` defined? Please show a (small) self-contained example and the exact error message.

Comment: And have a look at [Get nth character of a string in Swift programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language), which is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: What about reading the error message, figuring out what it says, and changing your code accordingly?

Comment: n.p I got it. All i need to do is if wmi.characterAtIndex(i) == String("a").utf16[0]

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert you `UniChar` - `characterAtIndex(i)` to a `Character`, so you can compare them.

**Solution:**

```
let ithChar:Character = Character(UnicodeScalar(string.characterAtIndex(i)))

if ithCahr == "a"
{
    //do some stuff

}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you could do it:

```
if string.characterAtIndex(i) == "a".characterAtIndex(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In better explanatory way, this can be one of the ways to perform what you intend to do.

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
var newString = str as NSString    

var num:Int = countElements(str)

for var i = 0; i < num; i++
{
    if (  Array(str)[i] == "p") {
        println(Array(str)[i]) // will show the output 

        println("success");
        break;
    }
}
```