# Swift 2.0 String with substringWithRange

Tags: ios, string, swift2

I am trying to get first char from String. It should be easy but I can't do in Swift 2.0 (with Xcode beta 6).

[Get nth character of a string in Swift programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language)

I have tried that method also. It use extension but I can't retrieve using that method. May I know how to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two solutions without casting to NSString

```
let string = "Hello"
let firstChar1 = string.substringToIndex(string.startIndex.successor())

let firstChar2 = string.characters.first
```

**Update for Swift 2:**

Since Swift 2 returns `Character` rather than `String` a new `String` must be created.

```
let firstChar2 = String(string.characters.first!)
```

**Update for Swift 3:**

`successor()` has been replaced with `index(after:..)`

```
let firstChar1 = string.substring(to:string.index(after: string.startIndex))
```

Comment: yes, casting is not necessary, because import Foundation is required, so free bridging does the job

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
let str = "hogehoge"
let text = (str as NSString).substringFromIndex(1) // "ogehoge"
```

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth (and for people searching for and finding this topic), without casting the String to NSString, you need to do the following with Swift 2.1:

```
let myString = "Example String"
let mySubString = myString.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: myString.startIndex.advanceBy(0), end: myString.startIndex.advanceBy(4)))

print(mySubString) //'Exam'
```

This would printout "Exam". Must say that it's much more verbose than in Obj-C. And that's saying something... ;-) But it gets the job done and without casting to NSString.

Comment: substringWithRange requires import Foundation. You don't need to cast because free bridging does the job

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
let myString = "My String" as NSString
myString.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2 a `String` is not a collection of anything. According to the documentation:

```
/// `String` is not itself a collection of anything.  Instead, it has
/// properties that present the string's contents as meaningful
/// collections:
///
///   - `characters`: a collection of `Character` ([extended grapheme
///     cluster](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#extended_grapheme_cluster))
///     elements, a unit of text that is meaningful to most humans.
///
///   - `unicodeScalars`: a collection of `UnicodeScalar` ([Unicode
///     scalar
///     values](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value))
///     the 21-bit codes that are the basic unit of Unicode.  These
///     values are equivalent to UTF-32 code units.
///
///   - `utf16`: a collection of `UTF16.CodeUnit`, the 16-bit
///     elements of the string's UTF-16 encoding.
///
///   - `utf8`: a collection of `UTF8.CodeUnit`, the 8-bit
///     elements of the string's UTF-8 encoding.
```

Assuming you want to find the second character,

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let chars = str.characters
let n = 2
let c = str.characters[str.characters.startIndex.advancedBy(n)]
```

Comment: @mservidio alternatively use let chars = str.characters.map{$0}; let c = chars[2];

Answer (score 0):

```
var mySuperCoolString = "Hello, World!!!!!!!!1!!";    
println(mySuperCoolString.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(mySuperCoolString.startIndex, 0), end: advance(mySuperCoolString.startIndex, 1))));
```

This should print out `H`

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 2.2 and Swift 3.0**

```
let string = "12134"
string.substringWithRange(string.startIndex..<string.startIndex.advancedBy(2))
```

Comment: actually for Swift 3 it is:
String.substring(with: Range<Index>)