# Get the first word in a String of words & spaces - Substring first word before space

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string that has words and spaces, "2h 3m 1s". I want to extract `2h` out of it; so get everything before first space.

```
var date = "1,340d 1h 15m 52s"  // I want to extract "1,340d".
```

What is the best practice of doing it? What substring function is the best approach?

Comment: stringbytrimming characters

Comment: @UmaMadhavi I don't just want to get rid of the all white spaces. I want to get the characters before first space.

Comment: use (date.componentSeparatedByString(" ") as! NSArray)[0]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24144365/5362916 please find this

Comment: I'd thought I'd mention that the accepted answer is *not the best approach* in this specific case. For large strings, both `split` and `componentSeparatedByString` give an unnecessary overhead when you just want the substring from start and up to a given character (" ").

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If your string is heavy, `componentsSeparatedByString()` tends to be faster.

**Swift 2:**

```
var date = "1,340d 1h 15m 52s"
if let first = date.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").first {
    // Do something with the first component.
}
```

**Swift 3/4/5:**

```
if let first = date.components(separatedBy: " ").first {
    // Do something with the first component.
}
```

Comment: Better approach! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great answer! Just keep in mind that in this example if the date string is empty, this will crash. You can do optional chaining to avoid this.

Comment: can this be modified to only return the first word if words are separated by new lines also?  This will now work for line return.

Answer (score 10):

In this context, neither the `.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")` method nor the `characters.split(" ")` method is the *"best approach"*. Both these methods will traverse the full `String` object, and give a `String` *array* as an result. Only after the array has been computed do we extract the first entry of this array. If we're treating a huge string, this is quite unnecessary in this context, and will result in an unnecessary overhead.

Instead, for a huge string, the following method is to prefer:

```
let firstDateEntryFast = date.substringToIndex((date.rangeOfString(" ")?.first)!)
```

This will look for the index of the first occurrence of `" "`, and thereafter return the substring from start of original string up only to the first occurrence. I.e., it will never investigate or make use of the original (in this context: assumed large) string beyond they point of the first `" "` occurrence.

You should note, however, that due to the force unwrap (operator (!)), this will crash at runtime if the string does not contain any instance of `" "`. So to stay safe, and follow the optional convention of Swift, use it in an `if let` clause:

```
if let myRange = date.rangeOfString(" ") {
    let firstDateEntryFast = date.substringToIndex(myRange.first!)
        // at this point, you know myRange is non-empty, and hence, .first can be
        // force-unwrapped
}
else {
    let firstDateEntryFast = date
        // no " " separation, unexpected? -> action
}
```

---

As in my first version of the answer, `split` can be used as an alternative (comparable with `componentsSeparatedByString`):

```
var date = "1,340d 1h 15m 52s"
let dateAsArray = date.characters.split(" ").map{ String($0) }
let firstDateEntry = dateAsArray[0]
```

Alternatively, skip storing them all in an array and directly get the first entry

```
var date = "1,340d 1h 15m 52s"
let firstDateEntryDirectly = String(date.characters.split(" ")[0])
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3 version

```
var str = "Hello, playground one two three"
let firstWord = str.components(separatedBy: " ").first
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code for your requirement

```
var date = "1,340d 1h 15m 52s"
print((date.componentsSeparatedByString(" ") as NSArray).objectAtIndex(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
var name = ""
if let optionalName = someOptionalString as? String {
    name = optionalName.contains(" ") ? (name.components(separatedBy: " ").first ?? "") : optionalName
}
```

First, we make sure the string is not nil.
Then, we use the ternary operator to assign it accordingly based on it it contains any spaces or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Scanner? It's pretty fast and powerful.

```
var date = "1,340d 1h 15m 52s"  // I want to extract "1,340d".
let scanner = Scanner(string: date)
if let first = scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: .whitespaces) {
    print("\(first)") // Prints "1,340d"
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner