# Swift 1.2, capture character from a word

Tags: xcode, swift

My problem is how to get character from a word

The result I needed is

```
DisplayChar("asd",1)
```

and it will display "a"

```
func DisplayChar(word : String, number : Int) -> String{
    let i: Int = count(word)
    var result = 0
    result = i - (i - number)
    var str = ""
    var j = 0

    for j = 0; j < result; j++ {
        str = str + word[j]
    }

    return str
}

DisplayChar("xyz", 2)
```

Comment: Why are you using Swift 1.2?

Comment: my school using it......

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
let sentence = "Hello world"
let characters = Array(sentence)
print(characters[0]) // "H"
```

Comment: This [online playground](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/try_swift.php) is still at 1.2. Only thing is it doesnt support modifications... So for every modification you have to copy, refresh the page, and paste before you can execute... but it works. :p

Comment: Thanks, I also try find substring.

Comment: func DisplayChar(word : String, number : Int) -> String{
    
let result = word.substringToIndex(advance(word.startIndex,number))
    
    return result

}

DisplayChar("xyz", 2)

Comment: @EricD: thank you. I updated my answer thanks to your link.

Comment: Thank you, but

 return String(word[number - 1]) 

this line of code in swift 1.2 it pop out subscript is unavailable error

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple good solutions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language) that may work, two good ones duplicated below.

**Convert to Array**

```
let word = "test"    
var firstChar = Array(word)[0] // t
```

(Note: this assumes a UTF8 or ASCII encoded string, but that is likely fine for school.)

**Create Your Own Extension**

First an extension of String to handle subscripts:

```
extension String {

  subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
    return self[self.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]
  }

  subscript (i: Int) -> String {
    return String(self[i] as Character)
  }

  subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
    let start = startIndex.advancedBy(r.startIndex)
    let end = start.advancedBy(r.endIndex - r.startIndex)
    return self[Range(start ..< end)]
  }
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
let word = "test"    
var firstChar = word[0] // t
```

Comment: func DisplayChar(word : String, number : Int) -> Character{
    
    let i: Int = count(word)
    
    var result = 0
    
     result = i - (i - number)
    
    let str = Array(word)
    var j = 0

    
    
    for j = 0; j < result; j++ {
        
       print(str[j])
    }
    
    return str
    
    
}

DisplayChar("xyz", 2)

I try to convert it to Array character but return type is string, how can I convert to string back again

Comment: Right now it looks like you are printing every character up to `number` and returning the full array of characters. From your initial post, it looks like you want to print just one character, in that case your print statement should not be in a loop. Can you describe what you expect `DisplayChar` to print and return?

Comment: the result of the code is like this

when user key in Display("xyz", 2)

the result become xy

when user key in Display("xyz", 1)

the result become x

Comment: Okay, don't print the string in the loop. Have some `var returnString = ""` and in the loop do `returnString = returnString + str[j]`. Then return the `returnString` at the end of the function.

Comment: Thanks, I will try tmr, coz is midnight 4am, i need to attend my class at 8.30pm.....

Answer (score -1):

Swift strings have a method called `substringToIndex`, `"asd".substringToIndex(1)` will return `"a"`.

I'm not sure if it works on Swift 1.2, though.

Comment: but what if I don't want use substring?? any other way??