# No '..<' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSRange Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I've migrated to Swift 3.0 and I'm now getting an error on this line:

```
let lastFourDigits = (accountNumber as NSString).substringWithRange(accountNumber.endIndex.advancedBy(-4)..<accountNumber.endIndex)
```

`No '..<' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange')`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `let lastFourDigits = String(accountNumber.characters.suffix(4))`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for index operations changed (see [Get nth character of a string in Swift programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language/24178591#24178591) and the full rationale: [Swift Evolution 0065](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md)):

```
let accountNumber = "XX0000000000000000001234"

let lastFourDigits = accountNumber[accountNumber.index(accountNumber.endIndex, offsetBy: -4)..<accountNumber.endIndex]

print("Last 4: \(lastFourDigits)")
```

No need to use `NSString` or `NSRange` in Swift.

A simpler syntax would also be:

```
let lastFourDigits = accountNumber.substring(from: accountNumber.index(accountNumber.endIndex, offsetBy: -4))
```