# Error: Editor placeholder in source file, when converting String extension to swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift3, range

```
    subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let start = startIndex.advancedBy(r.startIndex)
        let end = start.advancedBy(r.endIndex - r.startIndex)
        return self[Range(start: start, end: end)]
    }
```

Struggling to convert the above subscript in my String extension to swift 3. Below is what happened after I pressed the convert button on Xcode.

```
        subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
            let start = characters.index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.lowerBound)
            let end = <#T##String.CharacterView corresponding to `start`##String.CharacterView#>.index(start, offsetBy: r.upperBound - r.lowerBound)
            return self[(start ..< end)]
        }
```

[Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5feUHWffxoWRm1SYXV3WVlobEE/view?usp=sharing) of error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language has string subscripting methods for Swift 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is to add `characters` in front of index. The complier also gives you a hint to add a `String.CharacterView corresponding to`start`##String.CharacterView`. The message is maybe a bit fuzzy, but it contains great value! Tells you, that is expecting an array of characters. However, as @vadian suggests, you can even omit the `characters` from the beginning.

I have written a little test as well, just to make sure.

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.lowerBound)
        let end = index(start, offsetBy: r.upperBound - r.lowerBound)
        return self[start..<end]
    }
}

let string = "Hello world"
let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: 0, upper: 2))
let s = string[range] // prints "He"
```

Comment: You can even omit `characters` in both lines.

Comment: @dirtydanee you absolute legend!