# How can I properly guard a substring function in Swift 3?

Tags: swift

I have two similar functions to get a substring of a string in swift (I only need one):

```
func substring(start: Int, end: Int) -> String {
    let c = self.characters
    let r = c.index(c.startIndex, offsetBy: start)..<c.index(c.startIndex, offsetBy: end)
    let substring = self[r]
    return substring
}
```

and:

```
func substring(start: Int, end: Int) -> String {
    let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: start)
    let endIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: end)      
    return self[startIndex..<endIndex]
}
```

How can I properly guard this? Here is the main error I can get here:

> fatal error: cannot decrement before startIndex

I need to be able to send in all types of bad values into this function, such as negative `start`s and `end`s or `end`s that are less than `start`s. For the purpose of learning, let's assume there is a good reason to allow nonsense parameters in the function.

I have tried a few things, like:

```
func substring(start: Int, end: Int) -> String {
    guard end > 0 else {
        return "something"
    }

    let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: start)
    let endIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: end)      
    return self[startIndex..<endIndex]
}
```

but these either don't work or cause my app to freeze.

Answer (score -1):

You can deal with this yourself, but I would recommend looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language) if you want an easier time dealing with Swift Strings.