# In Swift, how to modify a character in string with subscript?

Tags: swift, string

Like in C, we can simply do

```
str[i] = str[j]
```

But how to write the similar logic in swift? 
Here is my code, but got error:
Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only

```
let indexI = targetString.index(targetString.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
let indexJ = targetString.index(targetString.startIndex, offsetBy: j)        
targetString[indexI] = targetString[indexJ]
```

I know it may work by using this method, but it's too inconvenient

```
replaceSubrange(, with: )
```

Comment: You answered your own question by proving that subscript is get-only.

Comment: I don't see why the subscript shouldn't be settable – it would functionally be the same as `.replaceSubrange(indexI...indexI, with: CollectionOfOne(targetString[indexJ]))`. You can always [file a bug/improvement](https://bugs.swift.org) over it.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language

Comment: This drives everyone crazy. But that doesn't make this a good question. Basically, you are just complaining. That's good for a blog, but not for Stack Overflow. You already gave the correct answer as to how to do this with `replaceSubrange`, so the question is pointless.

Comment: I'm not only complaining, I believe many people have the same feeling that managing String in Swift is painful comparing with other languages. Imaging you are doing coding interview with Swift, these tiny tedious syntaxes could drive me crazy and make bad impression for interviewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, a string (`char *`) can be treated as an array of characters.  In Swift, you can convert the `String` to an `[Character]`, do the modifications you want, and then convert the `[Character]` back to `String`.

For example:

```
let str = "hello"    
var strchars = Array(str)    
strchars[0] = strchars[4]    
let str2 = String(strchars)
print(str2) // "oello"
```

This might seem like a lot of work for a single modification, but if you are moving many characters this way, you only have to convert once each direction.

---

**Reverse a String**

Here's an example of a simple algorithm to reverse a string.  By converting to an array of characters first, this algorithm is similar to the way you might do it in C:

```
let str = "abcdefg"
var strchars = Array(str)

var start = 0
var end = strchars.count - 1

while start < end {
    let temp = strchars[start]
    strchars[start] = strchars[end]
    strchars[end] = temp
    start += 1
    end -= 1
}

let str2 = String(strchars)
print(str2)  // "gfedcba"
```

Comment: Thank you! It's the kind of solution I was expected. In this way we could focus on the logic itself, other than struggling with the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with `String` with Swift is major pain in the a**. Unlike most languages I know that treat string as an array of characters, Swift treats strings as collection of *extended grapheme clusters* and the APIs to access them is really clumsy. [Changes are coming in Swift 4](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/StringManifesto.md) but that manifesto lost me about 10 paragraphs in.

Back to your question... you can replace the character like this:

```
var targetString = "Hello world"
let i = 0
let j = 1

let indexI = targetString.index(targetString.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
let indexJ = targetString.index(targetString.startIndex, offsetBy: j)

targetString.replaceSubrange(indexI...indexI, with: targetString[indexJ...indexJ])

print(targetString) // eello world
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I was hoping some way similar to C, that's why selected another answer, but your answer is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was quite shocked as well by the fact that swift makes string indexing so damn complicated. For that reason, I have built some string extensions that enable you to retrieve and change parts of strings based on indices, closed ranges, and open ranges, PartialRangeFrom, PartialRangeThrough, and PartialRangeUpTo. You can **download the repository I created [here](https://github.com/Peter-Schorn/Swift_Utilities.git)**

You can also pass in **negative** numbers in order to access characters from the end backwards.

```swift
public extension String {

    /**
     Enables passing in negative indices to access characters
     starting from the end and going backwards.
     if num is negative, then it is added to the
     length of the string to retrieve the true index.
     */
    func negativeIndex(_ num: Int) -> Int {
        return num < 0 ? num + self.count : num
    }

    func strOpenRange(index i: Int) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let j = negativeIndex(i)
        return strOpenRange(j..<(j + 1), checkNegative: false)
    }

    func strOpenRange(
        _ range: Range<Int>, checkNegative: Bool = true
    ) -> Range<String.Index> {

        var lower = range.lowerBound
        var upper = range.upperBound

        if checkNegative {
            lower = negativeIndex(lower)
            upper = negativeIndex(upper)
        }

        let idx1 = index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: lower)
        let idx2 = index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: upper)

        return idx1..<idx2
    }

    func strClosedRange(
        _ range: CountableClosedRange<Int>, checkNegative: Bool = true
    ) -> ClosedRange<String.Index> {

        var lower = range.lowerBound
        var upper = range.upperBound

        if checkNegative {
            lower = negativeIndex(lower)
            upper = negativeIndex(upper)
        }

        let start = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: lower)
        let end = self.index(start, offsetBy: upper - lower)

        return start...end
    }

    // MARK: - Subscripts

    /**
     Gets and sets a character at a given index.
     Negative indices are added to the length so that
     characters can be accessed from the end backwards

     Usage: `string[n]`
     */
    subscript(_ i: Int) -> String {
        get {
            return String(self[strOpenRange(index: i)])
        }
        set {
            let range = strOpenRange(index: i)
            replaceSubrange(range, with: newValue)
        }
    }


    /**
     Gets and sets characters in an open range.
     Supports negative indexing.

     Usage: `string[n..<n]`
     */
    subscript(_ r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        get {
            return String(self[strOpenRange(r)])
        }
        set {
            replaceSubrange(strOpenRange(r), with: newValue)
        }
    }

    /**
     Gets and sets characters in a closed range.
     Supports negative indexing

     Usage: `string[n...n]`
     */
    subscript(_ r: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> String {
        get {
            return String(self[strClosedRange(r)])
        }
        set {
            replaceSubrange(strClosedRange(r), with: newValue)
        }
    }

    /// `string[n...]`. See PartialRangeFrom
    subscript(r: PartialRangeFrom<Int>) -> String {

        get {
            return String(self[strOpenRange(r.lowerBound..<self.count)])
        }
        set {
            replaceSubrange(strOpenRange(r.lowerBound..<self.count), with: newValue)
        }
    }

    /// `string[...n]`. See PartialRangeThrough
    subscript(r: PartialRangeThrough<Int>) -> String {

        get {
            let upper = negativeIndex(r.upperBound)
            return String(self[strClosedRange(0...upper, checkNegative: false)])
        }
        set {
            let upper = negativeIndex(r.upperBound)
            replaceSubrange(
                strClosedRange(0...upper, checkNegative: false), with: newValue
            )
        }
    }

    /// `string[...<n]`. See PartialRangeUpTo
    subscript(r: PartialRangeUpTo<Int>) -> String {

        get {
            let upper = negativeIndex(r.upperBound)
            return String(self[strOpenRange(0..<upper, checkNegative: false)])
        }
        set {
            let upper = negativeIndex(r.upperBound)
            replaceSubrange(
                strOpenRange(0..<upper, checkNegative: false), with: newValue
            )
        }
    }


}
```

Usage:

```
let text = "012345"
print(text[2]) // "2"
print(text[-1] // "5"

print(text[1...3]) // "123"
print(text[2..<3]) // "2"
print(text[3...]) // "345"
print(text[...3]) // "0123"
print(text[..<3]) // "012"
print(text[(-3)...] // "345"
print(text[...(-2)] // "01234"
```

All of the above works with **assignment** as well. All subscripts have getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

a new extension added,

since `String` conforms to `BidirectionalCollection` Protocol

```
extension String{
    subscript(at i: Int) -> String? {
            get {
                if i < count{
                    let idx = index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)
                    return String(self[idx])
                }
                else{
                    return nil
                }
            }
            set {
                if i < count{
                    let idx = index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)
                    remove(at: idx)
                    if let new = newValue, let first = new.first{
                        insert(first, at: idx)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

call like this:

```
var str = "fighter"

str[at: 2] = "6"
```