# How to perform compound queries with logical OR in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

From [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0):

> You can also chain multiple where() methods to create more specific queries (logical AND).

How can I perform an `OR` query?
Example:

1. Give me all documents where the field `status` is `open` OR `upcoming`
2. Give me all documents where the field `status == open` OR `createdAt <= <somedatetime>`

Comment: I had a similar question and now I'm editing my data schema so that the values are numbers with an intentional range (example: no access: 0, read access: 1, edit access: 2, owner access 3. Then I could query for an access field isGreaterThan, say, 1). Essentially, I'm thinking of leveraging the implicit OR in number ranges.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`OR` isn't supported as it's hard for the server to scale it (requires keeping state to dedup). The work around is to issue 2 queries, one for each condition, and dedup on the client.

---

**Edit (Nov 2019):**

Cloud Firestore now supports `IN` queries which are a limited type of `OR` query.

For the example above you could do:

```
// Get all documents in 'foo' where status is open or upcmoming
db.collection('foo').where('status','in',['open','upcoming']).get()
```

However it's still not possible to do a general `OR` condition involving multiple fields.

Comment: I understand the answer, but If I want to get all documents where the field `status` is `a` OR `b` OR `c` OR  `...` (let's say 50 OR). Do I need to perform 50 queries and join them? It doesn't appear super-optimal? Am I wrong? Is there a better way to approach this? Thx.

Comment: @nerotulip any success on this ?

Comment: I'm also wondering if there's a better solution than running N queries and joining on the client. Seems very inefficient.

Comment: This query should be availed to minimize firestore costs for developers

Comment: @GeekGuy Do you think Google wants less payments from their customers?

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: Dan, would you like to update this with the latest?  :-)

Comment: @DougStevenson what is the latest ? is there a way to do so today ?

Comment: @hkrlys Read kariem 's Answer below.

Comment: I may be biased, but I have a problem with the last edit:

This answer was great for the time it was posted. However, there had been an addition to Firestore which I addressed in my answer on Dec 6 2019. I do not think this answer should have been edited. In addition, the edit happened in January, not in November as indicated in the header.

Please see the discussion here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts

Comment: @Kariem, Sam is a colleague of mine working directly on Firestore. I've been a tad busy and have had less time to update information around the web than I use to. Think of this as an extension of a self edit, which is fine to update to amend new and changing information. I've also upvoted your answer.

Comment: The statement "it's hard for the server to scale" is nothing but a lame excuse for a lack of skills on Google's part. Just because your name is "Google" doesn't grant you automatic expertise in this field. Other indexing servers DO support the OR operator.

Answer (score 17):

With the [recent addition of IN queries](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html), Firestore supports "up to 30 equality clauses on the same field with a logical **OR**"

A possible solution to (1) would be:

```js
documents.where('status', 'in', ['open', 'upcoming']);
```

See [Firebase Guides: Query Operators | `in` and `array-contains-any`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any)

Support for general **OR** queries was announced at [Google I/O 2023](https://firebase.blog/posts/2023/05/whats-new-at-google-io#or-queries-in-firestore), so based on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries) a solution to (2) would be:

```js
query(collection(db, '{collection-name}'), or(
  where('status', '==', 'open'),   
  where('createdAt', '<=', somedatetime),   
));
```

See a full sample in GitHub/firebase: [snippets-node: index.js#orQueries](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/7b30935ff27dcdb4bacb845d67114e51eb3302cd/firestore/main/index.js#L655-L683).

Comment: This was the sollution I was looking for, thanks :D

Comment: The docs dont say where to you import `or` from?  It's not available in the web modular `@firebase/firestore` package.  I'd expect it to be there along with `query` , `where` etc.

Comment: @conor909 Here a link to the code snippets when using the `firebase-admin` package: https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/7b30935ff27dcdb4bacb845d67114e51eb3302cd/firestore/main/index.js#L655-L683. Also added this to the answer.

Comment: thanks @Kariem, but I'm using the web modular api `firebase/firestore`

Comment: @conor909 For web, I would need to set up a project to see if my assumptions are correct. I just checked: the link in the docs seems to go to a stale development branch ([test.firestore.js](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/7e4874cadf21d09e72a034d061abf390e8049f81/firestore-next/test.firestore.js#L1097-L1103)). However, looking at the source of the firebase NPM package, this looks like the right file: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/e30d7a6522fd3be0c30a82ee054b271a68c03fde/packages/firestore/src/api/filter.ts#L26. Does this help you?

Comment: @Kariem I'm a bit confused as to what that repo is, it seems to be a wrapper around both the web and node sdks?  There doesn't seem to be a clear entry point either, nor is there any docs so it's hard to tell how things are exported.  I appreciate you sending it on, I'll spend more time looking into it

Comment: I eventually found `or` by upgrading my `firebase/firestore` to version `10` - a bit confusing since the docs mentions the modular api is version `9`

Answer (score 3):

you can bind two Observables using the rxjs merge operator.
Here you have an example.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';

...

getCombinatedStatus(): Observable<any> {
   return Observable.merge(this.db.collection('foo', ref => ref.where('status','==','open')).valueChanges(),
                           this.db.collection('foo', ref => ref.where('status','==','upcoming')).valueChanges());
}
```

Then you can subscribe to the new Observable updates using the above method:

```
getCombinatedStatus.subscribe(results => console.log(results);
```

I hope this can help you, greetings from Chile!!

Comment: Would that still work with 5000 queries that have to be joined together afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

suggest to give value for status as well. 

ex.

```
{ name: "a", statusValue = 10, status = 'open' }

{ name: "b", statusValue = 20, status = 'upcoming'}

{ name: "c", statusValue = 30, status = 'close'}
```

you can query by `ref.where('statusValue', '<=', 20)`  then both `'a'` and `'b'` will found.

this can save your query cost and performance.

btw, it is not fix all case.

Answer (score 3):

I would have no "status" field, but status related fields, updating them to true or false based on request, like

```
{ name: "a", status_open: true, status_upcoming: false, status_closed: false}
```

However, check Firebase Cloud Functions. You could have a function listening status changes, updating status related properties like

```
{ name: "a", status: "open", status_open: true, status_upcoming: false, status_closed: false}
```

one or the other, your query could be just

```
...where('status_open','==',true)...
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't solve all cases, but for "enum" fields, you can emulate an "OR" query by making a separate boolean field for each enum-value, then adding a `where("enum_<value>", "==", false)` for every value that *isn't* part of the "OR" clause you want.

For example, consider your first desired query:

> 1. Give me all documents where the field status is open OR upcoming

You can accomplish this by splitting the `status: string` field into multiple boolean fields, one for each enum-value:

```
status_open: bool
status_upcoming: bool
status_suspended: bool
status_closed: bool
```

To perform your "where status is open or upcoming" query, you then do this:

```
where("status_suspended", "==", false).where("status_closed", "==", false)
```

How does this work? Well, because it's an enum, you know one of the values must have `true` assigned. So if you can determine that all of the *other* values don't match for a given entry, then by deduction it must match one of the values you originally were looking for.

#### See also

`in`/`not-in`/`array-contains-in`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any

`!=`: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/09/cloud-firestore-not-equal-queries.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't like everyone saying it's not possible.

it is if you create another "hacky" field in the model to build a composite...

for instance, create an array for each document that has all logical or elements

then query for .where("field", arrayContains: [...]

Answer (score 3):

Firebase introduced the [OR clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries) in 2023.

### Modular web example for a Web-client

```
import { or, collection, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(
  collection(db, "collection_name"), 
  or(
    where('status', '==', 'open'),
    where('createdAt', '<=', Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()))
  )
);
```

It is possible to combine `AND` with `OR` clauses:

```
import { and, or, collection, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(
  collection(db, "cities"), 
  and(
    where('state', '==', 'CA'),   
    or(
      where('capital', '==', true),
      where('population', '>=', 1000000)
  )
));
```

### Firebase function example

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import { Filter, getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  // your paramateres
});
const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

const result = await firestore.collection("cities")
  .where(
    Filter.or(
      Filter.where('capital', '==', true),
      Filter.where('population', '>=', 1000000)
    )
  )
  .get();
```

Comment: But how do I import "or"?

Comment: Hey @AdrianBartholomew, for a modular web UI version you can use `import { or, collection, query, and, where } from 'firebase/firestore'`.

Answer (score 2):

We have the same problem just now, luckily the only possible values for ours are A,B,C,D (4) so we have to query for things like A||B, A||C, A||B||C, D, etc

---

As of like a few months ago firebase supports a new query `array-contains` so what we do is make an array and we pre-process the OR values to the array

```
if (a) {
array addObject:@"a"
}
if (b) {
array addObject:@"b"
}
if (a||b) {
array addObject:@"a||b"
}
etc
```

And we do this for all `4!` values or however many combos there are.

THEN we can simply check the query `[document arrayContains:@"a||c"]` or whatever type of condition we need.

So if something only qualified for conditional `A` of our 4 conditionals (A,B,C,D) then its array would contain the following literal strings: `@["A", "A||B", "A||C", "A||D", "A||B||C", "A||B||D", "A||C||D", "A||B||C||D"]`

Then for any of those `OR` combinations we can just search `array-contains` on whatever we may want (e.g. "A||C")

---

Note: This is only a reasonable approach if you have a few number of possible values to compare OR with.

More info on [Array-contains here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52715590/2057171), since it's newish to firebase docs

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited number of fields, definitely create new fields with true and false like in the example above.  However, if you don't know what the fields are until runtime, you have to just combine queries.

Here is a tags OR example...

```js
// the ids of students in class
const students = [studentID1, studentID2,...];

// get all docs where student.studentID1 = true
const results = this.afs.collection('classes',
  ref => ref.where(`students.${students[0]}`, '==', true)
).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).pipe(
  switchMap((r: any) => {

    // get all docs where student.studentID2...studentIDX = true
    const docs = students.slice(1).map(
      (student: any) => this.afs.collection('classes',
        ref => ref.where(`students.${student}`, '==', true)
      ).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
    );
    return combineLatest(docs).pipe(

      // combine results by reducing array
      map((a: any[]) => {
        const g: [] = a.reduce(
          (acc: any[], cur: any) => acc.concat(cur)
        ).concat(r);

        // filter out duplicates by 'id' field
        return g.filter(
          (b: any, n: number, a: any[]) => a.findIndex(
            (v: any) => v.id === b.id) === n
        );
      }),
    );
  })
);
```

Unfortunately there is no other way to combine more than 10 items (use array-contains-any if < 10 items).

There is also no other way to avoid duplicate reads, as you don't know the ID fields that will be matched by the search. Luckily, Firebase has good caching.

For those of you that like promises...

```js
const p = await results.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
```

For more info on this, see [this article](https://dev.to/jdgamble555/firestore-many-to-many-mf8) I wrote.

J

Answer (score 0):

OR isn't supported

But if you need that you can do It in your code

Ex : if i want query products where (**Size** Equal Xl OR XXL : AND **Gender** is Male)

```
productsCollectionRef
                //1* first get query where can firestore handle it
                .whereEqualTo("gender", "Male")
                .addSnapshotListener((queryDocumentSnapshots, e) -> {

                    if (queryDocumentSnapshots == null)
                        return;

                    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
                        Product product = snapshot.toObject(Product.class);

                        //2* then check your query OR Condition because firestore just support AND Condition
                            if (product.getSize().equals("XL") || product.getSize().equals("XXL"))
                                productList.add(product);
                    }

                    liveData.setValue(productList);

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter dart language use this:

```
db.collection("projects").where("status", whereIn: ["public", "unlisted", "secret"]);
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

actually I found @Dan McGrath answer working here is a rewriting of his answer:

```
 private void query() {
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection("STATUS")
                .whereIn("status", Arrays.asList("open", "upcoming")) // you can add up to 10 different values like : Arrays.asList("open", "upcoming", "Pending", "In Progress", ...)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                        for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
// I assume you have a  model class called MyStatus

                            MyStatus status= documentSnapshot.toObject(MyStatus.class);
                            if (status!= null) {
                               //do somthing...!
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
```