# Firestore: Multiple conditional where clauses

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

For example I have dynamic filter for my list of books where I can set specific color, authors and categories.
This filter can set multiple colors at once and multiple categories.

```
   Book > Red, Blue > Adventure, Detective.
```

How can I add "where" conditionally?

```
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("book")
    .where("category", "==", )
    .where("color", "==", )
    .where("author", "==", )

    .orderBy("date")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {...
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

As you can see in the API docs, the [collection()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.10.x/Firestore#collection) method returns a [CollectionReference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.10.x/CollectionReference).  CollectionReference extends [Query](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.10.x/Query), and Query objects are immutable.  [Query.where()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.10.x/Query#where) and [Query.orderBy()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.10.x/Query#orderBy) return new Query objects that add operations on top of the original Query (which remains unmodified).  You will have to write code to remember these new Query objects so you can continue to chain calls with them. So, you can rewrite your code like this:

```
var query = firebase.firestore().collection("book")
query = query.where(...)
query = query.where(...)
query = query.where(...)
query = query.orderBy(...)
query.get().then(...)
```

Now you can put in conditionals to figure out which filters you want to apply at each stage. Just reassign `query` with each newly added filter.

```
if (some_condition) {
    query = query.where(...)
}
```

Comment: Edit: It works, when you reassign `query =`, I missed that... –  _This doesn't work for me. All of the where calls are simply ignored. Does this still work for you?_

Comment: Is this answer still true? 
Doing `this.afs.collection('events').doc(eventID).collection('activities').doc(activityID).collection('streams')` does not return a class that extends query.

Comment: @JimmyKane What is `afs`?  Are you using AngularFire?  If so, all your objects are different.  AF wraps everything into its own types.

Comment: yes its angular fire . Dang I need to check their docu then

Comment: It should be noted that while you can query by multiple where with different properties, you _still_ cannot query multiple where of the same property. Using your question as an example, there is still **no** solution to query `.where("category", "==", "adventure").where("category", "==", "detective")`

Comment: I do this solution using as @ThomasEbert said redefining `query =` but the problem is that I am using `typescript` any ideas to avoid `@ts-ignore`?

Comment: @pikilon This is just opinionated syntax. Typescript should allow you to redefine variables, using `let` to define them. I know that this is not recommended, because it can cause unexpected behavior due to scoping issues. If you just want to avoid the warning, the `@ts-ignore` will do just fine. Another thing that comes to mind is pushing each new result into an array: `const queries = [firebase.firestore().collection("book")]; queries.push(queries[queries.length - 1].where(...)); queries[queries.length - 1].get().then(...)`. Or you can write a wrapper class... Pick your poison ;-)

Comment: You can now with IN operator: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Note!

"You can perform range (<, <=, >, >=) or not equals (!=) comparisons only on a single field, and you can include at most one array-contains or array-contains-any clause in a compound query"
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries

Comment: @DougStevenson How would I do this with Web v9?

Comment: @blaytenshi you actually CAN do multiple where queries for the same field: `.where('category', 'in', ['adventure', 'detective'])` - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any

Comment: @inorganik I stand corrected, I guess firestore's finally added the capability! Will have to give firestore a try again some time :)

Answer (score 31):

**Firebase Version 9**

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) do not cover this but here is how to add conditional where clauses to a query:

```
import { collection, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore'

const queryConstraints = []
if (group != null) queryConstraints.push(where('group', '==', group))
if (pro != null) queryConstraints.push(where('pro', '==', pro))
const q = query(collection(db, 'videos'), ...queryConstraints)
```

The source of this answer is a bit of intuitive guesswork.

Comment: basically you don't use any extra firestore feature, you use the JS syntax to store the arguments in an array first, then use the spread syntax to spread the array into a sequence of arguments, within the query() argument list. well done

Answer (score 17):

##### With Firebase Version 9 (Jan, 2022 Update):

You can filter data with **multiple where clauses**:

```js
import { query, collection, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(
  collection(db, "products"),
  where("category", "==", "Computer"),
  where("types", "array-contains", ['Laptop', 'Lenovo', 'Intel']),
  where("price", "<=", 1000),
);

const docsSnap = await getDocs(q);
    
docsSnap.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.data());
});
```

Comment: Is there a link to the documentation for this?

Comment: @m.spyratos here is the documentation link 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries

Comment: Why google does that? based on the above signature of the `query` if you want to create a wrapper so that you can replace it with some other no sql, you simple can't. Why have such signatures? For each where condition repeating the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to @Doug Stevenson answer. When you have more than one `where` it is necessary to make it more dynamic as in my case.

```
function readDocuments(collection, options = {}) {
    let {where, orderBy, limit} = options;
    let query = firebase.firestore().collection(collection);

    if (where) {
        if (where[0] instanceof Array) {
            // It's an array of array
            for (let w of where) {
                query = query.where(...w);
            }
        } else {
            query = query.where(...where);
        }

    }

    if (orderBy) {
        query = query.orderBy(...orderBy);
    }

    if (limit) {
        query = query.limit(limit);
    }

    return query
            .get()
            .then()
            .catch()
    }

// Usage
// Multiple where
let options = {where: [["category", "==", "someCategory"], ["color", "==", "red"], ["author", "==", "Sam"]], orderBy: ["date", "desc"]};

//OR
// A single where
let options = {where: ["category", "==", "someCategory"]};

let documents = readDocuments("books", options);
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that a multiple `WHERE` clause is inherently an `AND` operation.

Answer (score 1):

For example, there's an array look like this

```
const conditionList = [
  {
    key: 'anyField',
    operator: '==',
    value: 'any value',
  },
  {
    key: 'anyField',
    operator: '>',
    value: 'any value',
  },
  {
    key: 'anyField',
    operator: '<',
    value: 'any value',
  },
  {
    key: 'anyField',
    operator: '==',
    value: 'any value',
  },
  {
    key: 'anyField',
    operator: '==',
    value: 'any value',
  },
]
```

Then you can just put the collection which one you want to set query's conditions into this funcion.

```
function* multipleWhere(
  collection,
  conditions = [{ field: '[doc].[field name]', operator: '==', value: '[any value]' }],
) {
  const pop = conditions.pop()
  if (pop) {
    yield* multipleWhere(
      collection.where(pop.key, pop.operator, pop.value),
      conditions,
    )
  }
  yield collection
}
```

You will get the collection set query's conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```
async yourFunction(){
    const Ref0 = firebase.firestore().collection("your_collection").doc(doc.id)

    const Ref1 = appointmentsRef.where('val1', '==',condition1).get();
    const Ref2 = appointmentsRef.where("val2", "!=", condition2).get()

    const [snapshot_val1, snapshot_val2] = await Promise.all([Ref1, Ref2]);

    
    const val1_Array = snapshot_val1.docs;
    const val2_Array = snapshot_val2.docs;

    const globale_val_Array = val1_Array .concat(val2_Array );

    return globale_val_Array ;
  }



/*Call you function*/
this.checkCurrentAppointment().then(docSnapshot=> {
      docSnapshot.forEach(doc=> {
          console.log("Your data with multiple code query:", doc.data());
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using angular fire, you can just use `reduce` like so:

```js
const students = [studentID, studentID2,...];

this.afs.collection('classes',
  (ref: any) => students.reduce(
    (r: any, student: any) => r.where(`students.${student}`, '==', true)
    , ref)
).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
```

This is an example of multiple tags...

You could easily change this for any non-angular framework.

For OR queries (which can't be done with multiple where clauses), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68966030/271450).

Answer (score 1):

Simple function where you can specify the path and an array of filters that you can pass and get you documents, hope it helps.

```
async function filterDoc(path, filters) {
  if (!path) return [];

  //define the collection path
  let q = db.collection(path);

  //check if there are any filters and add them to the query
  if (filters.length > 0) {
    filters.forEach((filter) => {
      q = q.where(filter.field, filter.operator, filter.value);
    });
  }

  //get the documents
  const snapshot = await q.get();

  //loop through the documents
  const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());

  //return the data
  return data;
}

//call the function
const data = await filterDoc(
  "categories_collection",
  [
    {
      field: "status",
      operator: "==",
      value: "active",
    },
    {
      field: "parent_id",
      operator: "==",
      value: "kSKpUc3xnKjtpyx8cMJC",
    },
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### With Firebase js SDK v9 (Jul, 2023 Update):

```
const citiesRef = db.collection('cities');
```

then you can combine constraints with a logical AND by chaining multiple equality operators (== or array-contains).

```
citiesRef.where('state', '==', 'CO').where('name', '==', 'Denver');
citiesRef.where('state', '==', 'CA').where('population', '<', 1000000);index.js
```

Reference to firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_and_queries)

Answer (score 0):

As `CollectionRef` does not have `query` method in firebase web version 9,

I modified [@abk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57766746/7184595)'s answer.

```js
async getQueryResult(path, options = {}) {
    /* Example
    options = {
      where: [
        ["isPublic", "==", true],
        ["isDeleted", "==", false]
      ],
      orderBy: [
        ["likes"],
        ["title", "desc"]
      ],
      limit: 30
    }
    */

    try {
      let { where, orderBy, limit } = options;

      let collectionRef = collection(<firestore>, path);
      let queryConstraints = [];

      if (where) {
        where = where.map((w) => firestore.where(...w));
        queryConstraints = [...queryConstraints, ...where];
      }

      if (orderBy) {
        orderBy = orderBy.map((o) => firestore.orderBy(...o));
        queryConstraints = [...queryConstraints, ...orderBy];
      }

      if (limit) {
        limit = firestore.limit(limit);
        queryConstraints = [...queryConstraints, limit];
      }

      const query = firestore.query(collectionRef, ...queryConstraints);
      const querySnapshot = await firestore.getDocs(query);
      const docList = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        return {
          id: doc.id,
          ...data,
        };
      });
      return docList;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This could be also a solution to this problem.**

```
async function filterCollection(collectionName, filterArr) {
    if (!collectionName) return [];
    let query = db.collection(collectionName);
    if (filterArr.length > 0) {
        filterArr.forEach((filter) => {
            query = query.where(filter.field, filter.operator, filter.value);
        });
    }
    const snapshot = await query.get();
    const response = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        return { id: doc.id, result: doc.data() }
    });
    return response;
}


  /**List the Data */
app.get("/list-documet-ids", async (req, res, next) => {
    const data = await filterCollection(
        "Users",
        [
            {
                field: "color",
                operator: "==",
                value: 'red',
            },
            {
                field: "categories",
                operator: "==",
                value: 'Detective',
            },
        ]
    );
    res.send(data);
});
```