# Multiple where clauses in Google CloudFirestore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-firestore, angular2-services

I am in Angular 4, I need to compose a query with the multiple where clauses. Here is my code below.
How can I add the multiple where clauses into the queryfn?

```
this.db.collection('cities', x => x.where('city', '==', 'CA'))
      .snapshotChanges()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036975/firestore-multiple-conditional-where-clauses?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), it is possible to either chain or append your clauses to the query reference:

```
// option 1
const ref = admin.firestore().collection('collectionName')
const query = ref.where('foo', '==', 'bar').where('baz', ==, 'buz')

query.get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(res => console.log(res.data())
  })

// option 2
const ref = admin.firestore().collection('collectionName')
const query = ref.where('foo', '==', 'bar')
query.where('biz', <=, 5)
query.where('zaz', ==, 9)

query.get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(res => console.log(res.data())
  })
```