# Is there a way to query a Firestore Collection with many 'where' in a loop?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to make a query on a collection of documents, each document contain an id that is in an array. The query should be dynamic because the ids in the array change frequently. I've tried this but it doesn't work

```
const postsCol = await admin.firestore().collection('posts')
idsList.forEach(elem => {
  postsCol.where('sentBy', '==', elem)
})
postsCol.orderBy("sentAt", "desc").limit(5)
```

Comment: From what I understand you're trying to query Firestore to get the posts by a list of authors. This type of `OR` query is currently not possible with Firestore. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987399/firestore-search-array-contains-for-multiple-values

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Frank, what is your opinion on the below answer by Renaud? Would appreciate your thoughts on chaining queries like that. My use case is to have 1 - 5 (max 20) in a list, each returning 30 documents with 30 fields each. Is it scalable?

Comment: On further research, I think the .where "in" is going to solve my problem as described here. Very useful feature. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query a Firestore collection, **you need to use the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html#get) method**.

Doing `const postsCol = await admin.firestore().collection('posts')` will not query the database, it just defines a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html). The same for `postsCol.where('sentBy', '==', elem)` or `postsCol.orderBy("sentAt", "desc").limit(5)`: they define a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query.html) but do not fetch the database.

Each query to a collection with the `get()` method is an asynchronous operation: the `get()` method returns a `Promise` which resolves with the results of the query.

Since you want to trigger several queries in parallel, you should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), as follows:

```
const queries = [];

idsList.forEach(elem => {
   queries.push(admin.firestore().collection('posts').where('sentBy', '==', elem).get());
})

Promise.all(queries)
.then(results => {
  //Do whatever you want with the results array which is an array of QuerySnapshots
  //See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html
})
```

---

**Note:** if you use this code in a Cloud Function, don't forget to return the Promises returned by the asynchronous operations (including the promise returned by `Promise.all()`).