# In ARRAY usage in Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to have a user select several sports teams from an NHL list or more specifically firebase to act like tags.

In a document I want to include an array that might have the tags of a story, #leafs, #senators #nhl.

Now I want to have the user interested in say #leafs #canadiens #nhl #ohl

I plan on storing the two in an array,

in Flutter

```
interestArray = ["leafs","canadiens",nhl,"ohl"]
```

So how do I,

get from Firebase interestArray from the array field "storyTags"?

```
  .where('storyTags', arrayContains: interestArray )
```

Is this supposed to work?

Comment: If I get you right, that should work. I once had a project with few friends and we did the same thing, that we stored our tags in an array that was in a users document.

Comment: I'm not sure if `arrayContains` can take an array as a parameter, I believe it takes only single strings. That's how I use it on my case though.

Comment: How do you compare multiple tags to multiple tags and get a query return.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, 'arrayContains' can only take a single value, rather than an array. So you could test `.where('storyTags', arrayContains: 'leafs')` but not `'leafs', 'canadiens'`

However, a similar question has been asked before: [Firestore search array contains for multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987399/firestore-search-array-contains-for-multiple-values). (tl;dr: Use a map.)

Adapting that solution might result in a schema like:

```
Stories:
  <docid>:
    title: "Leafs to play Canadiens"
    tags: {
      "leafs": true,
      "canadiens": true,
      "nhl": true
    }
```

And then to query it for all stories involving both the leafs and the canadiens, you'd use something like:

```
db.collection("Stories")
  .where("tags.leafs", "==", true)
  .where("tags.canadiens", "==", true);
```

(Note that Firestore does not support logical 'OR' queries; to do that, you'd need to issue separate queries and then merge the results. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)

**Update in response to comment:**

As mentioned above, it's unfortunately not possible to perform a logical 'OR' query. So to fetch all stories tagged with *either* team, you'd need to do something like this (in javascript):

```
var leafsSnapshot = await db.collection("Stories").where("tags.leafs", "==", true).get();
var habsSnapshot = await db.collection("Stories").where("tags.canadiens", "==", true).get();

// Concatenate the results together and log the story titles.
var stories = leafsSnapshot.docs.concat(habsSnapshot.docs);

// This won't quite work:
//
//     stories.forEach(story => console.log(story.get("title")));
//
// It won't de-duplicate stories, so any story that's tagged with *both*
// will be printed twice.

var seen = new Set([])
stories.forEach(story => {
  if (!seen.has(story.id)) {
    seen.add(story.id);
    console.log(story.get("title"));
  }
});
```

Alternatively, if you're not interested in 'AND' queries, you could go back to using arrayContains and follow a similar approach as above. i.e.:

```
var leafsSnapshot = await db.collection("Stories").where("storyTags", "arrayContains", "leafs").get();

// the rest is the same.
```

Comment: I am not looking for a solution where the game contains both the leafs and the Canadiens, I am looking for a solution where it contains _Either_  team not Both. 

I want to query all stories involving the leafs OR the canadiens 

Does the sample code work for or?

Answer (score 0):

We recently [announced](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html) that Cloud Firestore supports two new kinds of queries: "`in`" and "`array-contains-any`". They let you find documents with any of several values (up to 10).

That might help!