# whereArrayContains limit to 10

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to filter **questionCollection** on basis of **tagIDs** . Everything working fine but **whereArraycontains** is working for max 10 id's.

How could I improve my **structure** to work for more than 10 `tagIDs` and also make sure to call as less as hit to server to **reduce money spend**.

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- questions (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- qid (documents)
   |          |
   |          --- title: "Question Title"
   |          |
   |          --- qid: "autogeneratedID"
   |          |
   |          --- tagIDs =[tagID_1,tagID_2...tag_IDs_5] // array
   |
   --- tags (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- tagID (documents)
   |          |
   |          --- tagName: "Mathematics"
   |          |
   |          --- tagID: "autogeneratedID"
   |
```

fetch questions that contains specific tagIDs ( **fails if tagIDs greater than 10**)

```
private fun fetchQuestion(tagMap: HashMap<String, String>) {

        val tagIDList:MutableList<String> = ArrayList();
        for ((key) in tagMap) { 
            tagIDList.add(key);
        }
        var query: Query = db.collection(Constants.QUESTION_COLLECTION)
                .orderBy(Constants.KEY_QUESTION_ID, Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(50)
        if(!tagIDList.isNullOrEmpty())
            query = query.whereArrayContainsAny("tagIDs", tagIDList);//if list greater than 10 it's not working

        query.get().addOnSuccessListener { queryDocumentSnapshots ->
                if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty){
                    for (documentSnapshot in queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        val question = documentSnapshot.toObject(QuestionBO::class.java)
                    }
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                toast("No record found.")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should rethink the way you structure your data. Perhaps instead of having an array of tagID, you should have a separate collection that for a given ID returns a document of tagIDs and move on from there.

Comment: Did you found solution for your problem? I have same question.

Comment: The title of you question is "whereArrayContains limit to 10" while the content is about the limit of "whereArrayContainsAny". These two are different operations. Suggest change of title to "whereArrayContainsAny limit to 10."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for whereArrayContains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) queries is very specific.  It can only work with 10 array items:

> use the `array-contains-any` operator to combine up to 10 `array-contains` clauses on the same field with a logical `OR`

You should know that whereArrayContains does not reduce the number of billed document reads.  If your array contains 10 items, it will still cost 10 document reads.  If you perform 10 whereArrayContains queries, each with 10 array items, it will still cost 100 reads.

If you need N documents, there is no shortcut to make those N document reads cost less than the cost of N document reads.

Comment: Doug Stevenson , So can you suggest a better structure for fetching more than 10 tagIDs.

Comment: No, I cannot. You will have to query multiple times.

Comment: @DougStevenson If I have 100 image URLs as ArrayList and if I want to get() this 100 urls, it only counts as one document read right?

Comment: @DougStevenson suppose I have a array with 5 items in a document now if I query that document using `whereArrayContainsAny` does it count 5 read count?

Comment: @Arup yes, you can save Arrays of Strings for the Set of .where’s, when: without pronouns, repeats in Set, and I guess save it as an object or subdocument for an Array.length > 10

Comment: @Arup another solution for the problem would be to encode to your liking a 10mb string, which I will do to store on-device identifier for anonymous but attributable by encrypted-address-uid voting. If set on using ‘where’ for an Array field-type, optimize the Array to be queried as much as possible

Comment: does this still apply in 2023, the documentation removed the mention of the 10 item limit?