# Firestore Web - How many documents reads for using array-contains?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How many document reads do we pay for using `array-contains` query?

For instance,

Document 1 has a field called `serialNumberArray` with array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Document 2 has a field called `serialNumberArray` with array `[6, 7, 8]`

Document 3 has a field called `serialNumberArray` with array `[9, 10, 11, 12]`

---

So if we query `.where('serialNumberArray', 'array-contains', 10).limit(1)` how many reads will this cost?

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59658698/3073280

Answer (score 3):

Since your query is defined with `limit(1)`, if it exists one or more documents that correspond to the `array-contains` clause you will get only one document, and therefore you will pay for only one document.

If there is no document corresponding to the query, you will also pay for one document, since "there is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results", see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#minimum-charge).

---

Generally speaking, with a Firestore query, you only pay the number of reads corresponding to the number of documents returned by the query, not the number of documents in the collection.

Comment: Hi @choopage-JekBao, did you have the time to look at the proposed answer?