# Google Firestore - Search for multiple items presence in the array (and operation)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Consider a collection X . which has number of documents. There is a field Y which is an array.
I need to get all the documents which  contains ["val1","val2"]

The field Y can contain upto 40 to 60 values (out of possible 1000000 values).

As firestore allows only search of 1 value with arrary contains , what can be possible alternative.
I have already gone through - [Firestore search array contains for multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987399/firestore-search-array-contains-for-multiple-values)
But in my case because distinct names are more than 1 million - i would surpass the 200 max index limit

Comment: What your question?  Please edit the question to be clear.  If you're asking if Firestore limits can be exceeded, that's not possible (otherwise, they wouldn't be limits, right?).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67036384/4508504