# How to query the document which contains the given values in Firestore document?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore structure is shown in the picture

[image]

My Firestore document has many documents and one of them is shown the picture. In my Android App I want to query all the documents which has the values "3P", "Urgent" and "Mission Challenge". That means if a document has "3P", "Urgent" and "Mission Challenge" then this document should be my query result. If a document has only "3P" but not other values(like "Urgent", "Mission Challenge") then it should not come in my query result. How to do this in Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to perform something like `'array-contains-all'` in Firestore yet. @Doug had an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54987884/13130697) for a similar case.

> You can use at most one array-contains clause per query.

The best way for now would be using maps and using multiple `whereEqualTo` methods:

```
db.collection("dungeon")
    .whereEqualTo("textMap.3P", true)
    .whereEqualTo("textMap.urgent", true)
    .whereEqualTo("textMap.mission_challenge", true)
    .get()
```

The document:

```
{
  ...otherFields,
  textMap: {
    "urgent": true,
    ...otherMapFields
  }
}
```