# Cloud Firestore: Query a collection for an exact combination of strings present in a document

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to **query a collection for an exact combination of values in an object in a document**.

The 'array-contains' operator returns **all** the documents those properties appear across the collection when I'm looking to know if the exact combination **exist or not** in a document.

**EXAMPLE**:  In a 'styles' collection, each document has an array that includes a unique color combination of styles. I want to query to see if the exact combination of colors already exists in the collection in one of the documents.

Collection of 'styles':

```
   {
        "style1" : [ { "color" : [ "blue", "red"] } ],
        "style2" : [ { "color" : [ "blue", "red", "green" ] } ],
        "style3" : [ { "color" : [ "blue", "red", "yellow", "grey" ] } ],
        "style4" : [ { "color" : [ "red", "green" , "yellow" ] } ] 
   }
    
    
        let checkStyleExist = this.afs.collection("styles", ref => ref
        .where("color", "array-contains", ["blue", "red"]))
        .ref.get()
        
        checkStyleExist.docs.map(res => console.log(res))
```

**RESULT**:   I get a list of documents where blue and red appear. How do I query a collection for a document with the EXACT values in an object? The ["blue", "red"] does not work to query for an exact match.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore search array contains for multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987399/firestore-search-array-contains-for-multiple-values) Firestore doesn't currently support any query like `array-contains-all`. You can try converting the array to a map as mentioned in the linked answer. Here's another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165288/how-to-query-the-document-which-contains-the-given-values-in-firestore-document/68165655)

Comment: Indices won't work for what I'm trying to accomplish. I already tried it and Firebase generates an index in its console. 

I also tried  .where(`color.${colorCode.uid}`, '==', true)  but Firebase threw an error : 

"Try catch error triggered  FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Invalid field path (participants2.[object Object]). Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'"

I believe the where query only takes a string as a first parameter and won't a allow string interpolation.