# Flutter Firebase where query arrayContains in List

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchPageState createState() => _SearchPageState();
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final searchController = TextEditingController();
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  static const defaultSearch = "";
  String search  = defaultSearch ;

  void dispose() {
    searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    searchController.addListener(searchChanged);
  }

  searchChanged() {
    setState(() {
      search = searchController.text;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var tarifRef = _firestore
        .collection("vehicles")
        .where("models", arrayContains: search);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                child: Text(
                  "Vehicles",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20, fontFamily: "Quando", color: Colors.indigo),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 30, left: 30),
                child: TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  ),
                  controller: searchController,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.50,
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: tarifRef.snapshots(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot asyncsnapshot) {
                    if (asyncsnapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text("Error"),
                      );
                    } else {
                      if (asyncsnapshot.hasData) {
                        List<DocumentSnapshot> listOfDocumentSnapshot =
                            asyncsnapshot.data.docs;
                        return Flexible(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: listOfDocumentSnapshot.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Card(
                                color: Colors.indigo,
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    "${listOfDocumentSnapshot[index]["name"]}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    "${listOfDocumentSnapshot[index]["models"]}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  trailing: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.delete,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      await listOfDocumentSnapshot[index]
                                          .reference
                                          .delete();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This my all code and also I have database in Firebase like this;

```
vehicles: [
      {
        "name": "Vehicle1",
        "models": ["bus", "plane", "motorcycle"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Vehicle2",
        "models": ["motorcycle", "sporcar", "plane"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Vehicle3",
        "models": ["motorcycle", "plane", "bus"]
      }
    ]
```

In this example I can take one input from user, I can query and display which list includes this data but I want to query more than one data is in lists or not.

For example in this code if user input bus, program display Vehicle1 list but I want user can input more than one data such as plane and motorcycle. And so when the user input the plane and motorcycle,  I want it to be displayed the list of Vehicle 2 and Vehicle 3.

I try a lot of different ways but I can't found proparly solution to this problem.

[image: Firebase Documents1]

[image: Firebase Documents2]

[image: Firebase Documents3]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of a document you expect back from your query?

Comment: For example if user input bus and plane i want to see this view

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer; I meant a screenshot of a document from within the Firebase console.

Comment: I have added my firebase documents

Comment: My expectation from the code is to show which of these documents contains the entered variables. In my current code I can only query one variable with arrayContains method. But I want to do this;
for example I have list like this List<String> searchList = ["bus", "plane"]; and I want this usage var tarifRef = _firestore.collection("vehicles").where("models", arrayContains: searchList); but its not work.

Comment: Why arrayContains method cant query all elements of list at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `arrayContainsAny` here:

```
var tarifRef = _firestore
    .collection("vehicles")
    .where("models", arrayContainsAny: ["bus", "plane"]);
```

This query will return documents whose `models` array contains either `"bus"`, `"plane"` or both.

Also see the FlutterFire documentation for [`Query.where`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html).

Comment: Is there a way I can return documents that contain only both?

Comment: Nope. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987399/firestore-search-array-contains-for-multiple-values