# Firebase where query

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem, here is the code:

```
        const firstName = "rick";

        const users = await db.collection('user');

        if (firstName != undefined) {
            users.where("name", "==", firstName );
        }
        
        const snap = users.get();
```

why this query return me the whole document with all objects? How to do a query based on `where` clause that can be null or undefined? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not reassigning the `users` and hence it's fetching whole collection. Try refactoring like this:

```
let users: firebase.firestore.Query = db.collection('user'); 
//^ let instead of const

if (firstName) { 
  users = users.where("name", "==", firstName );
  // ^^ updating original 'users' value
}
        
const snap = users.get();
```

Comment: hmm, vscode throw me this: `Type 'Query<DocumentData>' is missing the following properties from type 'CollectionReference<DocumentData>':`

Comment: on `users` (lefthand) in `if` statement

Comment: @markWanka try adding the query type as in updated answer. CollectionRef seems a subclass of Query as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857851/dynamic-where-conditions-with-firestore-and-typescript)

Comment: thanks!, it works :)