# Firestore: Multiple where clauses

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
    let query = db.collectionGroup('volumes')
    query = query.where('days', 'array-contains', day)
    query = query.where('start_time', '<', time)
    query = query.where('end_time', '>', time)
    snapshot = await query.get().catch(e => console.log(e))
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data())
    })
```

**returns:**

> *code: 2,
> details: '',
> metadata: Metadata {
> internalRepr: Map { 'content-type' => [Array] },
> options: {}
> }*

**If I use only one "where" clauses its works just fine.**

For me its not working... [Firestore: Multiple conditional where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036975/firestore-multiple-conditional-where-clauses)

Comment: Did you try instructions mentioned in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_collection_groups

Comment: Its still raising the same error :\

Comment: can you show the complete logs from firebase --debug emulators:start including the failed transaction? Also is there anything in firestore-debug.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you're trying to perform is not supported by Firestore.  You can't have multiple range queries on different fields.  Be sure to read of the documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations).  Specifically:

> Queries can only perform range filters (>, <, etc) on a single field. **Queries with range filters on multiple fields are not supported.**