# How to programmatically form a firestore query?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a firestore query dynamically/programmatically based on user input. The problem is the input could be a variable amount unknown at the time of programming. I want to create the query in such a way that it will run if the user enters one input or many search terms.

My example code is in Kotlin for Android:

```
val searchFilters = listOf(
    "searchField1",
    "searchField2",
    "searchField3"
)
var refQuery= db.collection("myCollection")
for(filterName in searchFilters) {
  refQuery.whereEqualTo(filterName, true)
}
refQuery.get()
```

The above code doesn't appear to actually add any filter options and the entire collection is returned. What is the correct way to dynamically or programmatically create a firestore query?

**EDIT:** The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036975/firestore-multiple-conditional-where-clauses), but I'll leave this here for other's search reference as the way it is asked is worded differently enough to warrant it.

Have to reassign it to itself:

```
for(filterName in searchFilters) {
  refQuery = refQuery.whereEqualTo(filterName, true)
}
```

Comment: You have to reassign `refQuery` each time you add a conditional filter to it.  Query objects are immutable.

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave the edit here for reference as the way the question is asked might lead others here who want to know the same thing.