# Firestore not ordering my results depending on timestamp

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all my posts which time is newer ones first, I have made this query that should bring to me all the newest posts that I uploaded or other people did.

Thing is that I'm getting posts shuffled with timestamps , there are all mixed up instead of ordered by new ones

If I do the same query from the firebase console they are ordered the way it should

My `recyclerview` does **NOT** have any `reverselayout` or `stackfromend` attributes and I'm not expecting to use them, instead I just want my list to come from firebase ordered

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    suspend fun getLatestPosts(): Flow<Result<List<Post>>> = callbackFlow {

        val postList = mutableListOf<Post>()

        // Reference to use in Firestore
        var eventsCollection: CollectionReference? = null
        try {
            eventsCollection = firestore.collection("posts")
            eventsCollection.orderBy("created_at", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            // If Firebase cannot be initialized, close the stream of data
            // flow consumers will stop collecting and the coroutine will resume
            close(e)
        }

        val suscription = eventsCollection?.addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            if (value == null) {
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }

            try {
                postList.clear()
                for (post in value.documents) {
                    post.toObject(Post::class.java)?.let { fbPost ->
                        fbPost.apply {
                            created_at = post.getTimestamp(
                                "created_at",
                                DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior.ESTIMATE
                            )?.toDate()
                        }
                        postList.add(fbPost)
                    }
                }
                offer(Result.Success(postList))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                close(e)
            }
        }

        awaitClose { suscription?.remove() }
    }
```

Now if I sort the list locally after getting the data that works, but I don't want it to be client side, I want to have an ordered list from the server.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Posts timestamp are saved with `@ServerTimestamp` and Date format into Firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CollectionReference (Query) objects are immutable - they can't be changed once created.  They use a builder type pattern to construct new Query objects by adding constraints.  The original Query remains unmodified.

If you want to compose a set of operations to perform on a Query, you would have to remember the new Query returned by each operation.  An easy way to do this is by reassigning the prior Query if you no longer need it:

```
var eventsQuery: Query = firestore.collection("posts")
eventsQuery = eventsQuery.orderBy("created_at", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
```

Or you can do it as a chained sequence of operations, which is more idiomatic in the case that you know all the operations ahead of time:

```
val eventsQuery = firestore
    .collection("posts")
    .orderBy("created_at", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
```

If you need to conditionally apply operations, however, you will need to take the first approach.  A more detailed explanation can be found here: [Firestore: Multiple conditional where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036975/firestore-multiple-conditional-where-clauses/48037033)

Answer (score 1):

Problem was at this line

```
eventsCollection = firestore.collection("posts")
eventsCollection.orderBy("created_at", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
```

Seems like I need to wrap it up all into 1 line and make it a `Query`, it does not apply any changes to the `eventsCollection`, this can be done changing `CollectionReference` to `Query`

Comment: It doesn't have to be one line, but having this line is a no-op: `eventsCollection.orderBy("created_at", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)`. That's because all `orderBy` and `where...` methods are builders, and return a new `Query` object (instead of modifying the existing one). So you *can* have multiple lines, by: 1) changing the type of `eventsCollection` to `Query` (as you did). 2) then **assigning** the result of the builder back to the variable like: `eventsCollection = eventsCollection.orderBy("created_at", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)`