# How to Firestore set multiple filters/where clauses depen on User selection in React JS

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone explain how to set multiple filters inside the where clause programmatically or dynamically. I am using react JS i want to set multiple where clauses depend on user input. eg: 1st case User want to filter Status and Created time same time, 2nd case User want to filter status, Created time, Grade same time. How to set Filters depend on user selection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore: Multiple conditional where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036975/firestore-multiple-conditional-where-clauses)

Comment: This thread may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036975/firestore-multiple-conditional-where-clauses/48037033