# How may i Use 2 where logic in one query Firebase Flutter Application

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How may i Use 2 where logic in one Firebase Flutter Application

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('task')
                    .where('usergroup', isEqualTo: 'software')
                    .snapshots(),
```

Comment: .where('usergroup', isEqualTo: 'software','userid',isEqualTo: "ep434334",)



i want like this but not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore: Multiple conditional where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036975/firestore-multiple-conditional-where-clauses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple `where` for querying multiple conditions.

You can check the documentation [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage)

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('task')
    .where('usergroup', isEqualTo: 'software')
    .where('userid', 'ep434334')
```