# How do I perform a query to match all the elements in the provided array?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say, that in a document in field `students`I have a field, `subjects`,which is an array of strings that could be set up as follows:
`subjects = ["Computer Science,"Mathematics","Additional Mathematics"]`

And another array `subjectsToCompare = ["Computer Science","Mathematics"]`

How do I construct a query that returns all documents where the subjects field contains at least ALL the values in `subjectsToCompare`? It may contain other values, but it MUST contain all the values in subjectsToCompare.

Tried using "array-contains" and "in" but none of them give the desired behaviour.

Comment: Firestore doesn't have such a query.  Consider using a different way of structuring your data to at least make it possible, as shown in the duplicate.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you. I have tried modifying my data structure as recommended. But subjectsToCompare could be of any length, whereas in the duplicate questions the length is known, and hence you can chain multiple where queries. How do I do so, if I do not know the length of the array?

Comment: That sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036975/firestore-multiple-conditional-where-clauses