# Combine posts from different tags in Firestore

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, document-database

I have some posts in Firestore collection name `posts`. Each post has a `tags` collection.

```
posts : {

  Id1: {

     tags: {tag1: true, tag2: true}
    },
  Id2: {

     tags: {tag12: true, tag21: true}
    },
   Id3: {

     tags: {tag31: true, tag2: true}
    },
...
}
```

With this structure I can filter to get the post with specific tags.

```
db.collection('posts').where('tags.tag2', '==', 'true').limit(10)
```

However if I want to filter `posts` on multiple tags I only have this idea:

```
x= db.collection('posts').where('tags.tag2', '==', 'true').limit(5)
y= db.collection('posts').where('tags.tag1', '==', 'true').limit(5)
page1 = x + y
```

But how if I have more tags (10 tags or more). How can I combine them with the limitation for each pages  `10` and go to next page with an optimized algorithm.

Comment: There is no way to do a single query for all of the values (see [How to perform compound queries with logical OR in Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632042/how-to-perform-compound-queries-with-logical-or-in-cloud-firestore)). So you'll have to do a separate query (of 10) for each tag, and then combine them client-side.

Comment: I didn't ask for single query. I know there is no single query. I'm asking for combining post algorithm. It is like pagination but the different is I want to get better idea not to get same posts. I know the pagination in Firestore to but this for multiple request which needs better algorithm.

Comment: Hello @AmirMovahedi, what you have seems like a recipe for matching (tag2 OR tag1) and while I cannot comment on how to optimize the merge there, I think if you are by chance looking for (tag2 AND tag1) then chaining might suffice like so: `db.collection('posts').where('tags.tag2', '==', 'true').where('tags.tag1', '==', 'true').limit(5)` ... what are your thoughts?