# Firestore whereEqualsTo from arraylist

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to list documents that matches field String value from ArrayList.

Simply:

- I have ArrayList with tags stored at runtime
- and documents with field **tag**

and I want to query documents that matches tag with one of tags stored in ArrayList. Is this possible with official query or does I have to download all documents and filter it client-side? Thanks for any answers.

Also, this is my method generating query:

```
public static Query getQueryForFollowed(DocumentSnapshot snapshots) {
    if (snapshots == null || !snapshots.exists()) {
        return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("posts").whereEqualTo("null", "null"); // return query that will get nothing
    }
    ArrayList<String> f = processFollowedTags(snapshots);
    Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("posts")
            .whereEqualTo("tag", f.get(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < f.size(); i++) {
        query = query.whereEqualTo("tag", f.get(i));
    }
    return query;
}
```

I have debugged code and query has contained requested conditions, but query didn't found any document matching it.

Comment: Can you share the structure of your db ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/k0us5i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more search on Google I have found that querying field to multiple values is not available.

According to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46633294/8428193
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/321

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("posts")
            .whereEqualTo("tag", f.get(0)).orderBy("tag", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);;
```

Comment: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter tag

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet may help you.

```
fun arrayContainsQueries() {
    // [START array_contains_filter]
    val citiesRef = db.collection("cities")
    citiesRef.whereArrayContains("regions", "west_coast")
    // [END array_contains_filter]
```

}

ref : [git](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/master/firestore/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/firestore/kotlin/DocSnippets.kt)

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Kotlin in my app

Answer (score 0):

As of Nov 2019 this is now possible to do with the `in` query.

> With the in query, you can query a specific field for multiple values
> (up to 10) in a single query. You do this by passing a list containing
> all the values you want to search for, and Cloud Firestore will match
> any document whose field equals one of those values.

it would look like this:

```
 Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("posts")
    .whereIn("tag", f);
```