# Google Cloud Firestore - how to do an OR query for array items

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to find a way to do an OR query in a collection of "object" documents.

Each object document has a "type" field which is an array.

```
object1:
 - name:
 - description:
 - types:["type-a","type-b","type-d"]
 - createdOn


object2:
 - name:
 - description:
 - types:["type-a","type-d"]
 - createdOn


object3:
 - name:
 - description:
 - types:["type-d","type-h"]
 - createdOn

object4:
 - name:
 - description:
 - types:["type-b"]
 - createdOn
```

How can I do a query such that I get the object documents that either belongs to type-a or type-b? For example, for the above case of a collection, the result should be object1,object2,object4 ordered by createdOn field if possible.

Note that there are millions of "object" documents. So the operations should be as efficient as possible performance-wise, cost-wise, data transfer rate wise (battery life for a mobile app).

Very much appreciated!

Comment: Cloud Firestore currently does not support this type of query (internally called an `IN` query), since we haven't yet figured out how to do so while maintaining our performance guarantees. For the moment you'll have to do a separate query for each value, and then merge the values client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Cloud Firestore currently does not support this type of query (often referred an IN query), since we haven't yet figured out how to do so while maintaining our performance guarantees.

For the moment you'll have to do a separate query for each value, and then merge the values client-side.

Also see:

- [How to perform compound queries with logical OR in Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632042/how-to-perform-compound-queries-with-logical-or-in-cloud-firestore), which is about more general `OR` queries.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. Do you know if there are any plans to make this possible in the future? I mean is the team working on it? Is there any feature requests from the community?

Comment: Hi Frank. What would you say about this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028262/react-native-firestore-paging-with-multiple-parallel-promises-inside-promise-all I would like to hear your opinion on this... That problem is born out of this one...