# Firebase Database operator "OR"

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

how can make a query with `or`

Example:

```
select * from people where eyes ="Blue" or eyes ="Green"
```

I use Firestore and can make when `"whereEqualTo"` but I need that.

My code in Android now is:

```
db.collection("people")
  .whereEqualTo("eyes","Blue");
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot that use two fields "eyes" and "hair",  in firebaseFirestore has whereIn but is not possible have multiple whereIn

Comment: The accepted answer of the duplicate is out of date, but look at this specific answer, which is up to date.  You want to use an 'in' query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216840

Answer (score 1):

If the Firestore Query documentation found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) we have a section on limitations.  There is an explicit coverage of *OR*.

It reads:

> Cloud Firestore provides limited support for logical OR queries. The
>   in and array-contains-any operators support a logical OR of up to 10
>   equality (==) or array-contains conditions on a single field. For
>   other cases, create a separate query for each OR condition and merge
>   the query results in your app.