# Creating a complex query in firebase firestore in Android

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

i have a collection "Orders", having a srtucture like this

```
dishname :
  "Biryani"
dishprice: 
  "350"
dishquantity: 
  "1"
hotelemail: 
  "apk@gmail.com"
hotelname : 
  "Apk"
time
  April 13, 2020 at 2:51:11 PM UTC+5
useremail
  "checking@gmail.com"
username
  "pasha"
usernum
  "03416889912"
orderstatus
  "Pending"
```

now i want's to perform a query on this collection which resembles like this
get ALL the orders where (orderstatus == "Pending" OR (orderstatus == "collected" AND useremail = "someemail") OR (orderstatus == "distapched" AND useremail = "someemail")

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not possible in a single query, since [Firestore doesn't support logical OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632042/how-to-perform-compound-queries-with-logical-or-in-cloud-firestore) in the way that you're specifying here.  Instead of a logical OR, you will have to instead perform separate queries for each OR condition, and merge the results in the client.  So, in your specific case, you will need three queries for:

- orderstatus == "Pending"
- (orderstatus == "collected" AND useremail = "someemail")
- (orderstatus == "distapched" AND useremail = "someemail")

  Then your code can take the results and filter out duplicate documents if needed.