# Tag based filtering implementation Firestore

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection with a field called `categories`. Which contains an array of object `["cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", "cat5", "cat6", "cat7", "cat8", "cat9", "cat10",`cat11`]`.(Over 10 categories in the array).

When try to do the `whereArrayContainsAny` it gives an error `INVALID_ARGUMENT: A maximum of 10 'IN' or 'ARRAY_CONTAINS_ANY' filter values are allowed at once.` So I won't be able to take this array as this. Then I read some articles and they say to maintain a map of data such as,

```
catagories
  |_cat1 : true
  |_cat2 : false
  |_cat3 : false
```

Are there any performance issues if I use this method? And is there a way to use the same existing array method to do this filtering when categories are over 10?

What I tried is,

```
Firestore db = FIRConnection.initFIRConnection();

// Create a reference to the cities collection
CollectionReference deliveries = db.collection("data");

// Create a query against the collection.
Query query = deliveries.whereArrayContainsAny("categories", Arrays.asList("cat1",
                "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", "cat5", "cat6", "cat7", "cat8", "cat9", "cat10", "cat11"));

// retrieve  query results asynchronously using query.get()
ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot = query.get();

for (DocumentSnapshot document : querySnapshot.get().getDocuments()) {
    System.out.println(document.get("categories"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you'll run into with this choice is that Firestore [doesn't support logical OR queries among multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632042/how-to-perform-compound-queries-with-logical-or-in-cloud-firestore).  If you want to know if **any** of N categories is set on a document, you'll have to query **each** of the N categories individually on the client.  That might not be what you want, as you'll possibly be reading documents many times over for each query.

You might have better luck splitting your list of categories into batches of 10, querying each batch separately using arrayContainsAny, then merging the results of each of those queries on the client.