# Firestore Query not equal to Uid

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I apologize for having to ask this question, I have been researching countless links but have not been able to find it. It seems simple but has been far from it.

I know that you can not do a not equal to query in firestore, thus my code is the following:

```
private void getNotEqual() {
    // db defined elsewhere
    Query query = db.collection("collection")
            .whereLessThan("uid", user.getUid())
            .whereGreaterThan("uid", user.getUid())
            .orderBy("uid");

    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Size: " + task.getResult().size());
        }
    });
}
```

But it is still not returning the documents where it is not equal. The Uid is from Firebase Authentication and is stored as a string as a field in the document. Am I missing something here?

Thank you sincerely in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query is **always** going to return no documents. It is effectively asking for all documents whose uid field is both greater than **and** less than a certain value, which is an impossible condition to satisfy.  The filters in a Firestore query are logically AND'd together.  They are not logically OR'd.  [Firestore does not support logical ORs in queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632042/how-to-perform-compound-queries-with-logical-or-in-cloud-firestore).

It sounds like you want to perform two separate queries, then combine the results in the client.  One query will have `whereLessThan("uid", user.getUid())` and the other `whereGreaterThan("uid", user.getUid())`.  But honestly, it might be easier for you just to get **all** the documents in the collection, and manually filter out the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

[Firestore v21.7.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#firestore_v21-7-0) introduces not equal queries, so you can now use:

```java
private void getNotEqual() {
    // db defined elsewhere
    Query query = db.collection("collection")
            .whereNotEqualTo("uid", user.getUid())
            .orderBy("uid");

    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Size: " + task.getResult().size());
        }
    });
}
```