# How to form a firestore query comparing two fields in a single collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to firebase and databases in general so pardon me if it's something trivial.
My collection looks like this:

```
Rooms{
  Room1{
    roomName,
    user1,
    user2,
  },...
}
```

I wanted to filter the results so I can get only rooms that have **user1** field different than id of the current user and **user2** equal to an empty string.

I've read that there is no OR in firestore queries, you can't do it like this

```
const openRoomsQuery = roomsRef.where("user1", "!=", user.uid).where("user2", "==", "");
```

nor like this

```
const notMineRoomsQuery = roomsRef.where("user1", "!=", user.uid);
const openRoomsQuery = notMineRoomsQuery.where("user2", "==", "");
```

How can I do this in a fairly simple way (possibly without putting user fields to a single array field)?

Comment: This type of query is not supported by Firestore.  You can only compare fields to specific values provided in the where clause.

Comment: What do you mean? I've done it both ways I provided code for. I just wasn't using "!=" in those. It worked fine. (Oh yeah. It didnt work for a second one I guess. Sorry)

Comment: I think I misread the question, but the disposition is the same - Firestore does not support logical OR queries.  You have to perform two queries and merge the results in the app.  Your question is effectively a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632042/how-to-perform-compound-queries-with-logical-or-in-cloud-firestore