# Query if field equals value or is null

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to filter a collection by a field value and also get all entries where the field is equal to null. Since the in operator does not support null values, I can not take the simple route and query for:

```
where('field', 'in', ['value', null])
```

I am currently solving this issue by having two queries. One getting the entries where the field is null and one getting the entries where the field equals the value:

```
where('field', '==', 'value')
where('field', '==', null)
```

But this returns me more entries than necessary, and I have to sort and merge the entries client side. I would rather have a single query return me all entries, so I can do things like pagination across the combined list, rather than paginating over both list separately.

Is there any method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Doug's answer, I'll say that it might be a workaround, which is instead of storing `null`, you can store null as a string. That being said, the following query:

```
where('field', 'in', ['value', 'null'])
//
```

Will return the desired results. Not ideal, but it will do the job.

Comment: Hey Nestoto. Have you tried the solution in my answer? Does it work?

Comment: works like a charm, i am just not completely sold on the idea to convert every null value to 'null' and convert every string i get from the database that equals 'null' to null. could lead to some weird interactions in rare cases

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. Yep, that's just a workaround that can be used until such operations will be possible.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is currently no alternative to making multiple queries for each condition.  [Firestore does not support logical "OR" queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632042/how-to-perform-compound-queries-with-logical-or-in-cloud-firestore), except for "in" (which does not work for this specific case, as you have seen).