# Merge two Future<QuerySnapshots>

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I need to merge two queries into one and return a `Future<QuerySnapshot>`. My code is not merging query2 into query1, it is only returning docs in query1. Code below:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> mergeQueries() async {
    QuerySnapshot query1 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('practice')
        .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
        .where('teamId', isEqualTo: widget.teamId)
        .where('checkSinglesDoubles', isEqualTo: dropDownType)
        .where('player1name', isEqualTo: playerNameFilter)
        .get();

    QuerySnapshot query2 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('practice')
        .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
        .where('teamId', isEqualTo: widget.teamId)
        .where('checkSinglesDoubles', isEqualTo: dropDownType)
        .where('player2name', isEqualTo: playerNameFilter)
        .get();

    query1.docs.addAll(query2.docs);

    return query1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `docs` property of a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) object is read-only, so calling `query1.docs.addAll(query2.docs)` has no effect.

There is no way to combine two queries (or their corresponding query snapshots)  into one. This makes sense - since on the server side Firestore does not support [logically compound queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632042/how-to-perform-compound-queries-with-logical-or-in-cloud-firestore) in general.

What you could could do instead is to extract the documents (or the data they contain) from the `QuerySnapshots` and combine those with each other. This will change your return type, but provide the functionality you were looking for.

```
Future<QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>> mergeQueries() async {
  var query1 = await ...;
  var query2 = await ...;

  var combinedDocs = query1.docs;
  combinedDocs.addAll(query2.docs);
  return combinedDocs;
}
```