# SQL LIKE operator in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been using Firebase Real Time Fatabase for a while and I come across Cloud Firestore today. I can't figure out on how to use LIKE operator on Firestore.

Firebase Real Time Database

```
ref.child('user').orderByChild('name').startAt(name).endAt(name+'\uf8ff')
```

On Cloud Firestore, I have tried

```
userRef.where('name', '>=', name); <br>
userRef.where('name', '<=', name);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 38):

To solve this, you need to change `orderByChild` function with `orderBy`. So please use the following code:

```
ref.collection('user').orderBy('name').startAt(name).endAt(name+'\uf8ff')
```

Comment: this doesn't work when the app requires another order By for pagination purpose along with .startAfter() and .endBefore(). we cant expect that while using this trick, we have to deactivate the pagination functionality which is not right.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't an equivalent to LIKE, but you can do prefix filtering in the same way you do it in RTDB.

The query you have written is the same as equals. You need to do the same end by trick and do just less than `<`.

Comment: See also advice given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568142/google-firestore-query-field-contains-on-where-method . In short, you can partially emulate this if you segment the words you might be searching for ahead of time.

Answer (score 3):

FYI: With the later versions of cloud firestore (e.g. 0.12.5), the startAt() and endAt() methods require a list of strings, not a single string.

Answer (score 3):

**Update for Firebase version 9**

```
import { query, collection, getDocs, orderBy, startAt, endAt } from "firebase/firestore";

//db is exported from your firebase.js file

const ref = collection(db, "user");

const q = query(ref, orderBy('name'), startAt(name), endAt(name+'\uf8ff'));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no such operator, allowed ones are `==, <, <=, >, >=.`
Here you can find all the limitations of queries in cloud firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries