# How can i use wild card searching in firestore without using third party app

Tags: firebase, search, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

Is there any way to search data from firestore like sql query with "like, or, and keyword" without help of any third party app like algolia or elastic search

Comment: Cloud Firestore supports prefix searches (e.g. words starting with a certain substring), but does not support the equivalent of a SQL `LIKE` operation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642641/sql-like-operator-in-cloud-firestore

Comment: You can take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O6x-ZJp-10)** where I have explained step by step, how you can achieve this.