# How to use startAt() and endAt() in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I read Dan McGrath's answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642641/sql-like-operator-in-cloud-firestore) in which he says that in Firestore there is an equivalent for the following line of code:

```
myRef.startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");
```

This line works perfect in Firebase Realtime database but I'm trying to find the equivalent in Cloud Firestore for days. Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use startAt() in firestore if that is what you are asking about

Comment: @PeterHaddad How? Please provide me the exact equivalent in Firestore. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

### Query filters

You can add query filters using the `.where` keyword. Take a look at [Order and Limit Data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

### Query cursors

If you want to use cursors for paginating data, take a look at [Paginate Data with Query Cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)

### Your query

You need to specify which field you are wanting to search.  For example, if you're looking for all documents with a `name` containing the `searchText` you will need to add an `orderBy` parameter.

```
myRef.orderBy("name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");
```

This assumes that your `myRef` is a reference to a collection.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your answer. Can you please provide me the exact equivalent in Firestore? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my response to add the `orderBy` parameter, which you are missing.

Comment: @Jason Berryman - How can I make startAt and endAt case insensitive?

Comment: @umeshlohani - This is not possible, as all entries are case sensitive. This may be a good use case for a full text search service, such as Algolia.  You could create a separate `search` collection which contains both uppercased and lowercased entries, with pointers to the original document.  When a new document is added to the main collection, trigger a Cloud Function to add upper and lower cased versions to the `search` collection

Answer (score 1):

you find the solution, maybe you confuse, just change this " with single quotes (')
and it will works perfectly thanks for the other post it helps me too.
I leave my code here:

```
FirestoreRecyclerOptions <Ingreso> newoptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Ingreso>()
                .setQuery(fStore.collection("DatosEmpresa").orderBy("DepartamentoEmpresaLoweCase").startAt(newText.toLowerCase()).limit(25).endAt(newText.toLowerCase()+'\uf8ff'),Ingreso.class)
                .build();
```