# How to search list of data from firebase firestore using android searchView

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the Cloud Firestore of Firebase to store users and the android Searchview to provide search fonctionnality. When a user search for "jonathan" for example, if he begin typing "j" i want to bring in all users with the name starting par "j". How can i achieve this ?

Here is what i have tried:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SEARCH " + query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                searchUsers(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SEARCH " + newText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                searchUsers(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

Getting the user from Firebase:

```
private void searchUsers(String recherche) {
    if(recherche.length() > 0)
    recherche = recherche.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + recherche.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    listUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    db.collection("users").whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("name", recherche)
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        System.err.println("Listen failed:" + e);
                        return;
                    }
                    listUsers = new ArrayList<User>();

                    for (DocumentSnapshot doc : snapshots) {
                        User user = doc.toObject(User.class);
                        listUsers.add(user);
                    }
                    updateListUsers(listUsers);
                }
            });
}
```

This works only for the first letter "j" as soon as i add "ja" for example i still have all the "jonathan" displayed

Comment: You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642641/sql-like-operator-in-cloud-firestore/) out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of @Oby if found the solution. In fact i dont really need to query the database every time the search is triggered since i have the list of users. I just have to make the search on the list like this:
We get the list first:

```
private void getUsers() {
        db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("etat", 1)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            System.err.println("Listen failed:" + e);
                            return;
                        }
                        listUsers = new ArrayList<User>();

                        for (DocumentSnapshot doc : snapshots) {
                            User user = doc.toObject(User.class);
                            listUsers.add(user);
                        }
                        updateListUsers(listUsers);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Here is the search function:

```
private void searchUsers(String recherche) {
        if (recherche.length() > 0)
            recherche = recherche.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + recherche.substring(1).toLowerCase();

        ArrayList<User> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for(User user : listUsers){
            if(user.getName() != null && user.getName().contains(recherche)){
                results.add(user);
            }
        }
        updateListUsers(results);
    }
```

Here i notify the the Adapter of the RecyclerView that the data changed:

```
private void updateListUsers(ArrayList<User> listUsers) {

        // Sort the list by date
        Collections.sort(listUsers, new Comparator<User>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
                int res = -1;
                if (o1.getDate() > (o2.getDate())) {
                    res = 1;
                }
                return res;
            }
        });

        userRecyclerAdapter = new UserRecyclerAdapter(listUsers, InvitationActivity.this, this);
        rvUsers.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        rvUsers.setAdapter(userRecyclerAdapter);
        layoutManagerUser = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        rvUsers.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerUser);
        userRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And of course the SearchView:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SEARCH " + query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                searchUsers(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SEARCH " + newText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                searchUsers(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: But you are getting all list of users, what if you have one million user ? i think you need to load it by page using FirestorePagingAdapter for example

Answer (score 2):

My way of searching is rather inefficient as I am using two recyclerviews, one is hidden and the other with the data visible. All data in the document is fetched to an array and I query the array in real-time as you want. The data remains synced always so it seems real-time. Not a good practice but it gets the job done for me. If you need further help I can create a gist for you in that.

The proper way would be to use this official link to search for exactly what you need
[Full-text search](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search)