# Where, Firestore queries on Flutter, doesnot have "notEqualTo" condition

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching a data from fire-store I have an order Object which have a status as an attribute that can be "pending"," delivering","delivered".

What I want to do is getting all the orders except the one with status "delivered"*.

How I can do that with Where clause ?

```
return _fs
        .collection('orders')
       // .where('status', ' ', 'delivered')
        .where('deliveryTime', isGreaterThan: startTime)
        .where('deliveryTime', isLessThan: endTime)
        .snapshots();
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Firestore queries cannot filter for fields that do not have a certain value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195122/firestore-comparison-operators-contains-does-not-contain-starts-with

Answer (score -1):

You can view the ["**Query limitations**" section in the querying article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> Cloud Firestore does not support the following types of queries:
>
> - Queries with a `!=` clause. In this case, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example, although the query clause `where("age", "!=", "30")` is not supported, you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the clause `where("age", "<", "30")` and one with the clause `where("age", ">", 30)`.

```dart
return _fs
        .collection('orders')
        .where('status', isGreaterThan: 'delivered')
        .where('status', isLessThan: 'delivered')
        .snapshots();
```

### However

As you can see, I removed the range filter on `deliveryTime` because it is *impossible* to perform range filters on multiple fields as [explained here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries):

> You can only perform range comparisons (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) on a single field, and you can include at most one `array-contains` clause in a compound query[.]