# Firestore query a document based on starts with in any of the 2 fields

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore set up is the following:

Collection : Users |
DocumentID : [Auto-generated] |
Fields -> 
name: robert downey jr,
username: iron_man

I would like to query this document with a search query like "robert" or "rob" or "iron" or "ir". How do I do this in Firestore? I tried whereArrayContains() but that query looks for perfect match rather than starts with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in one query, because Firestore [does not support logical OR queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632042/how-to-perform-compound-queries-with-logical-or-in-cloud-firestore) that span multiple fields.  What you can do instead is make two queries, one for `name`, and the other for `username` that do string prefix sorts (read other questions about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568142/google-firestore-query-on-substring-of-a-property-value-text-search), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195122/firestore-comparison-operators-contains-does-not-contain-starts-with), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115422/is-there-a-way-to-search-sub-string-at-firestore)).  Then, after you do both queries, merge the results on the client to build the final list of results.