# Firestore Rules for Roles and Users

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a similar like the role-based access (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access) within my firestore database. But the roles like I defined them are not working. I'm always getting the error with

```html
Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

What I have so far is the following in my firestore rules:

```html
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }

    function getRole(rsc) {
      return rsc.data.roles[request.auth.uid];
    }

    function isOneOfRoles(rsc, array) {
      return isSignedIn() && (getRole(rsc) in array) || isSignedIn() && rsc.data.openWorld == true;
    }
   
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read: if isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
    }
 
    // Match any document in the 'worlds' collection
    match /worlds/{world} {
      allow read: if isOneOfRoles(resource, ['owner', 'writer', 'commenter', 'reader']);
    }
  }
}
```

My document structure looks like: ROOT/worlds/{WORLDID}/...
and every document in there like the following:

```html
{
  name: "Open World",
  desc: "", 
  openWorld: true,
  roles: {
    DzpqsN6QjmZoCoM0eymWJ17VKbG3: "owner"
  }
}
```

I'm using this with an Angular Frontedn and Angularfire with the following code which is wrapped into a service:

```html
getWorlds(userId): Observable<any> {
  return this.afs.collection('worlds').snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    }).catch((e: any) => Observable.throw(this.errorHandler(e)));
}
```

Can anybody see where there might be an error in there or is there a general bug with firestore at this point? Thanks!

Comment: You should also include the read/write data/code you used to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit following your comment:*

Your query fails "because it does not include the same constraints as your security rules". See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_authuid.

In other words, you cannot rely only on the security rule **to filter** the documents the user can read and you have to build your query accordingly. However, this will not be possible with your current data structure since Firestore does not support the logical OR queries (e.g. the following will not be possible owner OR writer, owner OR openWorld, etc.).

---

I've thoroughly tested your rules and they seem to work correctly for all the cases, i.e. with the different roles, in the case `openWorld = true` and no correct role is declared, in the case `openWorld = false`, etc. Are you sure your user is correctly signed in? Did you wait enough time for the rules to "propagate"?

Here is the JavaScript code used for testing

```
var docRef = firestoredb.collection("worlds").doc("x9fwf0Wi528OBlGYIZz1");

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("xxxx@xxx.com", "xxxxx")
    .then(function(userCredential) {

   docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
          console.log("Document data:", doc.data());

      } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
      }

   }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
   });

});
```

Finally, here is a suggestion: I would maybe refactor your rules to separate the case `isOneOfRoles` and the case `isOpenWorld`, like e.g.:

```
    function isOneOfRoles(rsc, array) {
      return isSignedIn() && (getRole(rsc) in array);
    }

    function isOpenWorld(rsc) {
      return isSignedIn() && rsc.data.openWorld == true;
    }

   .....

    // Match any document in the 'worlds' collection
    match /worlds/{world} {
      allow read: if isOneOfRoles(resource, ['owner', 'writer', 'commenter', 'reader']) || isOpenWorld(resource);
    }
```

Comment: @AndréKool You might be right, I don't really know... The OP asks "Can anybody see where there might be an error in there or is there a general bug with firestore at this point?". If you think I should remove it, I have no problem to do so.

Comment: I will leave that decision to OP. They can best determine the usefullnes of your post.

Comment: Yes, I waited enough time (more than 10min) for my rules to apply. When I'm testing my code just with the isSignedIn() it is working. Because of that, I think that the error is somewhere in the getRole() function. Does it maybe come from my call to the collection itself (I inserted it into the original question)? I want to query all entries, the user is permitted to, not one specific.

Comment: OK, thanks! I understood what's the problem. 
But how can I do this in my frontend script. I have to write a where condition, that checks if the current user is part of my .roles set. Something like the following:
ref.where("roles", "contains", user.uid)

Comment: Look at the first answer of this SO post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568142/google-firestore-query-on-substring-of-a-property-value-text-search. But this method would oblige you to keep four objects, one for each role and do several queries. I think you will have to change your data model anyhow.