# Check for Substring inside a document in Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple Users collection in my Firestore data, that has few properties. this is how it looks:
[image]

I'm trying to implement a search option in my application, and I want it to be able to get a substring too. So if I have two users, for example:

```
demouser
hellouser
demotest
```

And I search for "demo" it will give me both, `demouser` and `demotest`.
I searched, but found only old answer (an year or so old) and saw that it is not possible in Firestore, This is what I tried from an answer I saw:

```
func searchForName(find name: String, completion: @escaping([User]?)->()){
    var usersFound: [User] = []
    db.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).whereField(USER_NAME, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: name).whereField(USER_NAME, isLessThanOrEqualTo: name).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if err == nil {
            guard let results = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            print(results[0].get(USER_MAIL))
        }
    }
}
```

But it didn't work. I tried with `arrayContains` too, but got no results at all.
Is there any option to find a substring of a field in Firestore at all?

EDIT: My current code is based on the answer from here: [Google Firestore: Query on substring of a property value (text search)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568142/google-firestore-query-on-substring-of-a-property-value-text-search) which does not work for me.

Comment: Interesting question. This is a great question for Doug Stevenson, though I don't think I can cc him in a comment. I'll look into and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Still not possible to do substring searches (except string prefixes with the `>` operator).  That's not likely to change in the near future, so I'd suggest using another database alongside Firestore that can do this, though it won't be as scalable as Firestore.