# search by substring in flutter with bloc

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, bloc

I store data in firestore and I want to query it using substrings. How can I perform a search with BLoC in flutter? I'm using Firestore and I need to search some items by substring from it.

I fail to understand how to properly perform a search. Could you share me some links with guides or examples?

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this article](https://medium.com/flutterpub/when-firebase-meets-bloc-pattern-fb5c405597e0) that explains how to request Firestore from flutter using the BLoC pattern. It's explained step by step and you will be able to reproduce it in order to understand the whole process.

You will also be introduced to "collections" and "documents", things that you should know when querying your database. Bear in mind that as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46568525/10810527) you will not be able to filter just with the request, so you will have to request all the documents and filter them on your app.