# Firebase-Functions error after update. What can I do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I updated my firebase-functions and now I get this error in the Firebase console. The code is still the same, but I get an error now:

```
/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/collection-group.js:54
    async *getPartitions(desiredPartitionCount) {
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:39:28)
```

This is my cloud function TypeScript source:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

/********************************************************************/

exports.newChatMessage = functions.firestore
  .document('/games/{gameId}/chat/{chatId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const createData = snap.data();
    if(!createData) {
        return false;
    }

    const chatMessage = createData.message;
    if(!chatMessage) {
        return false;
    }

    console.log('New Chat message in game: ', context.params.gameId);

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'New chat message',
            body: chatMessage,
            icon: 'ic_notification'
        }
    }

    return admin.firestore().collection(`/games/${context.params.gameId}/members`).where( 'notificationChat', '==', true ).get().then( members => {
        members.forEach( member => {
            if(member.id !== createData.user) {
                return admin.firestore().doc(`/users/${member.id}`).get().then( memberdata => {
                    if( memberdata.get('firebaseToken') === '' ) {
                        return memberdata.data();
                    } else {
                        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(memberdata.get('firebaseToken'), payload).catch( error => { console.log(error) });
                    }
                }).catch( error => { console.log(error) });
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        })
    }).catch( error => { console.log(error) });

});
```

What is this? In my functions there isn't any method named `*getPartitions`.

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate what you upgrade path was.  What *exactly* did you change to produce this error?  There should be enough information in your question so that anyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Which version of Node?

Comment: im still using node 8.. but this is the same as before

Comment: Firebase libraries require Node 10. Install from legacy-8 for Node 8 support: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore#supported-nodejs-versions

Comment: so the only way is to use node 8 is with legacy-8.. the other way would be to subscribe to blaze ?

Comment: I got the same error. I downgrade: firebase-admin  and firebase-functions to a version I new that worked before: "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",   "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1" and it worked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Downgrade firebase-admin and firebase-functions to version: "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0", "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1" and it will work.

Thanks to [Marcel Hoekstra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64575650/firebase-functions-error-after-update-what-can-i-do#comment114208082_64575650) for posting this in the comments.

Comment: i tried it also, but for me it doesnt work... i also tried to downgrade the firebase-tools but still the same error :(

Comment: ahhh okay thank you guys, npm install command gives me errors, but the firebase depoy command is working :)

Comment: That's the working solution! **IMPORTANT:** don't run `npm audit fix --force` to fix vulnerabilities (mine had 4) because it won't help. As mentioned, just downgrade, run `npm install` and deploy your functions.

Comment: This did not work for me until I downgraded @google-cloud/firestore using legacy-8 as suggested by @guy-incognito to ^3.8.6.

Answer (score 3):

As [Uzbekjon stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64575650/firebase-functions-error-after-update-what-can-i-do/65079853#65079853), you can get this error if running node `v8` instead of `v10`. Some comments mentioned this was not the desired solution, because they didn't want to upgrade to Firebase's Blaze plan. Unfortunately, there's not going to be much of a choice in the matter soon.

If you go to your Firebase Functions in the console, you'll notice a warning that "Node V8 has been deprecated". As of Feb 15 2021 you will no longer be able to make changes to or deploy any functions using Node.js V8. As of March 15, 2021 you will no longer be able to use the functions at all. They will be completely blocked from execution.

Blog post *[Migrate your Firebase Cloud Functions to Node.js 10](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/migrate-your-firebase-cloud-functions-to-node-js-10-d9c677933ee)* was really good for explaining how to upgrade to `v10`. I follow the author's steps and redeployed - no error and no deprecation warning.

**Required Updates**

1. Check to make sure you have at least Node.js V10 installed globally on your machine `node --version`.
2. `npm install -g firebase-tools@latest` (you need at least version *8.1.0*)
3. In your *package.json* file, make sure Node.js V10 is targeted like this:

   ```
    "engines": {
      "node": "10"
    }
   ```
4. Check your Firebase environment variables. The source I linked to goes into further detail and links other explanation sources, but basically upgrading might mean default environment variable names have changed (I didn't have to change anything here).

**Recommended**

1. Make sure `firebase-functions` is at least version `3.7.0`. I had to update this anyway to solve another error.

**Optional, but still recommended**

1. Update your compiler options in `tsconfig.json`. This will make it so unnecessary language versions are not transpiled.

   ```
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2018",
      "lib": ["es2018"],
    }
   ```
2. Test your code :)

Like I mentioned earlier, making this upgrade removed the error for me. Once I made a new deployment, all deprecation warnings were also removed from the Firebase Functions console.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get this error if you are running Node.js `v8`. Upgrading to Node.js `v10` resolves this error.

If you are managing your Node.js version using `nvm`, then run:

```
nvm install v10 --lts
```

I think it is a better solution than downgrading the `firebase-admin` library.

Comment: maybe but for this you will need to upgrade to blaze plan, and this is not what i want :)

Comment: Whether you want to upgrade to the Blaze plan or not, this is probably the better solution because Node 8 is deprecated with Firebase. This means that come February 2021 none of your functions will work

Comment: if i would change to blaze plan, is there a possibility to limit the costs? i dont want to pay for that, if a user makes millions of reads to my firestore ...