# How to integrate search functionality to React app with firebase firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, search, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I have a React app with firebase's firestore database. I want search functionality in my app. I wanted to integrate Algolia search. But the problem occurred when I saw that firebase's free Spark Plan does not allow requests to external APIs. So I can't integrate Algolia.
I will be highly appreciated it if anyone tells me how can I integrate search functionality to my app using the firestore database(It should update and add data when my firestore data changes or adds)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+free+search

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Firestore: Query on substring of a property value (text search)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568142/google-firestore-query-on-substring-of-a-property-value-text-search)