# Firestore Querying by Search Term

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using a Firebase v9 project. In my Firestore database, I have a collection of records. Each of these records is a type of credit card. A given record looks something like the following:

[image]

I am looking to make a search functionality in which users can use keywords to search for a specific `Type` in the entire collection on cards. How do I properly query the Firebase collection using the user's search term? (Assuming the user does not need to exact match and just needs a substring within the `Type` field).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568142/google-firestore-query-on-substring-of-a-property-value-text-search) post seems a bit outdated, but is in the right direction...

Comment: Firestore doesn't support full text search yet. You can follow the linked answer or alternatively use a service like Algolia.

Comment: The post you cited is not out of date.  This is not a capability of Firestore.